# How to replace the NULL values in a pivot output with zeroes?

Tags: sql-server, matrix

Following the answer [from a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321404/convert-vertical-to-horizontal-layout-sql) I want to get rid of some NULL values when I do not have a number for some cases

I have the following query

```
CREATE TABLE [MYTABLE]
  (
      [A] int
    , [B] int
    , [VAL] float
  );

INSERT INTO [MYTABLE] ([A], [B], [VAL]) VALUES
    (1, 1, -218.46),
    (1, 2, -2.1846000000000e+02),
    (2, 1, 6.4000000000000e+01),
    (2, 2, -218.46),
    (2, 3, 6.4000000000000e+01),
    (3, 2, -2.1846000000000e+02),
    (3, 3, -218.46),
    (4, 3, 6.4000000000000e+01),
    (4, 4, -218.46),
    (4, 5, 6.4000000000000e+01),
    (5, 4, 6.4000000000000e+01),
    (5, 5, -218.46),
    (5, 6, 6.4000000000000e+01),
    (6, 5, 6.4000000000000e+01),
    (6, 6, -218.46),
    (6, 7, 6.4000000000000e+01),
    (7, 6, 6.4000000000000e+01),
    (7, 7, -218.46),
    (7, 8, 6.4000000000000e+01),
    (8, 7, 6.4000000000000e+01),
    (8, 8, -218.46),
    (8, 9, 6.4000000000000e+01),
    (9, 8, 6.4000000000000e+01),
    (9, 9, -218.46),
    (9, 10, 6.4000000000000e+01),
    (10, 9, 6.4000000000000e+01),
    (10, 10, -218.46);
    
SELECT [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]
FROM
(   SELECT  x = a
        ,   y = b
        ,   v = (CASE WHEN IsNumeric(val)=0 THEN 0 ELSE val END)
    FROM    MYTABLE
) AS T
PIVOT
(
    min( v)
    FOR y IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]) 
) AS pvt
order by x
```

I am getting the following result:

```
    1       2      3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10
------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- 
-218.46 -218.46   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL  
64      -218.46    64     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL  
  NULL  -218.46 -218.46   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL 
  NULL    NULL     64   -218.46    64     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL 
  NULL    NULL    NULL     64   -218.46    64     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL  
  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL     64   -218.46    64     NULL    NULL    NULL  
  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL     64   -218.46    64     NULL    NULL  
  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL     64   -218.46    64     NULL  
  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL     64   -218.46    64
  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL     64   -218.46
```

but I need the following result

```
    1       2      3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10
------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- 
-218.46 -218.46   NULL    NULL     0       0       0       0       0       0    
64      -218.46    64      0       0       0       0       0       0       0    
   0    -218.46 -218.46    0       0       0       0       0       0       0   
   0       0       64   -218.46    64      0       0       0       0       0   
   0       0       0       64   -218.46    64      0       0       0       0    
   0       0       0       0       64   -218.46    64      0       0       0    
   0       0       0       0       0       64   -218.46    64      0       0    
   0       0       0       0       0       0       64   -218.46    64      0    
   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       64   -218.46    64
   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       64   -218.46
```

How do I replace all NULL values with 0's?

## EDIT

Following @Siva answer

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Matrix]
(
        [A]     INT
    ,   [B]     INT
    ,   [VAL]   FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Matrix] ([A], [B], [VAL]) 
    VALUES
        (1, 1, -218.46)
    ,   (1, 2, -2.1846000000000e+02)
    ,   (2, 1, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (2, 2, -218.46)
    ,   (2, 3, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (3, 2, -2.1846000000000e+02)
    ,   (3, 3, -218.46)
    ,   (4, 3, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (4, 4, -218.46)
    ,   (4, 5, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (5, 4, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (5, 5, -218.46)
    ,   (5, 6, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (6, 5, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (6, 6, -218.46)
    ,   (6, 7, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (7, 6, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (7, 7, -218.46)
    ,   (7, 8, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (8, 7, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (8, 8, -218.46)
    ,   (8, 9, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (9, 8, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (9, 9, -218.46)
    ,   (9, 10, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (10, 9, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (10, 10, -218.46);

    SELECT  COALESCE([1], 0)    [1]
        ,   COALESCE([2], 0)    [2]
        ,   COALESCE([3], 0)    [3]
        ,   COALESCE([4], 0)    [4]
        ,   COALESCE([5], 0)    [5]
        ,   COALESCE([6], 0)    [6]
        ,   COALESCE([7], 0)    [7]
        ,   COALESCE([8], 0)    [8]
        ,   COALESCE([9], 0)    [9]
        ,   COALESCE([10], 0)   [10]
    FROM
        (   
            SELECT  x = a
                ,   y = b
                ,   v = val
            FROM    [dbo].[Matrix]
        ) AS dataToPivot
        PIVOT
        (
            MIN(v)
            FOR y IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10])
        ) AS pivoted
    ORDER BY x;
```

What woul be the best way to do this in a dynamic for, I was thinking to do FOR THE FIRST PART...:

```
DECLARE @sql  nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @Flag INT;
DECLARE @Size INT;
SET @Flag = 1   
SET @Size = 10 ;
SET @sql = 'SELECT '+ CHAR(13); 
WHILE (@Flag <= @Size) BEGIN
  SET @sql =  @sql + ' COALESCE([' + cast( @Flag as varchar(10))  + '], 0)    ['+ cast( @Flag as varchar(10))+'],'+ CHAR(13)  ;
  SET @Flag = @Flag + 1;  
END
SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 2)
SET @sql =  @sql + '
 FROM
        (   
            SELECT  x = a
                ,   y = b
                ,   v = val
            FROM    [dbo].[Matrix]
        ) AS dataToPivot
        PIVOT
        (
            MIN(v)
            FOR y IN (';
SET @Flag = 1   
WHILE (@Flag <= @Size) BEGIN
  SET @sql =  @sql + ' [' + cast( @Flag as varchar(10))  + '],';
  SET @Flag = @Flag + 1;  
END 
SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 1);
SET @sql =  @sql +             
            ')
        ) AS pivoted
    ORDER BY x;'
   print  @sql
exec(@sql);
```

Comment: Looks like you have two options... COALESCE or ISNULL.  Take your pick :)

Comment: I was planing to make all that and then do exec( ) statement

Comment: You should ask a new question instead of appending to the original one.  You'll get more responses.

Comment: actually the code I wrote would be the answer, do you think I should write a question about how to solve the same but more elegant??

Comment: You could... but what you wrote looks pretty good to begin with in terms of dynamic sql.  Maybe ask, "is there a way to specify column names for a pivot query without dynamic sql?  Possibly from another table?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE` to achieve the result.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20d43/1)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Matrix]
(
        [A]     INT
    ,   [B]     INT
    ,   [VAL]   FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Matrix] ([A], [B], [VAL]) 
    VALUES
        (1, 1, -218.46)
    ,   (1, 2, -2.1846000000000e+02)
    ,   (2, 1, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (2, 2, -218.46)
    ,   (2, 3, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (3, 2, -2.1846000000000e+02)
    ,   (3, 3, -218.46)
    ,   (4, 3, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (4, 4, -218.46)
    ,   (4, 5, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (5, 4, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (5, 5, -218.46)
    ,   (5, 6, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (6, 5, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (6, 6, -218.46)
    ,   (6, 7, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (7, 6, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (7, 7, -218.46)
    ,   (7, 8, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (8, 7, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (8, 8, -218.46)
    ,   (8, 9, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (9, 8, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (9, 9, -218.46)
    ,   (9, 10, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (10, 9, 6.4000000000000e+01)
    ,   (10, 10, -218.46);

    SELECT  COALESCE([1], 0)    [1]
        ,   COALESCE([2], 0)    [2]
        ,   COALESCE([3], 0)    [3]
        ,   COALESCE([4], 0)    [4]
        ,   COALESCE([5], 0)    [5]
        ,   COALESCE([6], 0)    [6]
        ,   COALESCE([7], 0)    [7]
        ,   COALESCE([8], 0)    [8]
        ,   COALESCE([9], 0)    [9]
        ,   COALESCE([10], 0)   [10]
    FROM
        (   
            SELECT  x = a
                ,   y = b
                ,   v = val
            FROM    [dbo].[Matrix]
        ) AS dataToPivot
        PIVOT
        (
            MIN(v)
            FOR y IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10])
        ) AS pivoted
    ORDER BY x;
```

Comment: I was trying to make a loop, but do not know how to...
`DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

WHILE
BEGIN
    SET @sql... 
END`

Answer (score 2):

How about IsNull?

```
SELECT 
isnull([1], 0) as [1],
isnull([2], 0) as [2],
isnull([3], 0) as [3],
isnull([4], 0) as [4],
isnull([5], 0) as [5],
isnull([6], 0) as [6],
isnull([7], 0) as [7],
isnull([8], 0) as [8],
isnull([9], 0) as [9],
isnull([10], 0) as [10] 
FROM 
(SELECT x=a, y=b, v= CASE WHEN IsNumeric(val)=0 THEN 0 ELSE IsNull(val, 0) END FROM MYTABLE)
as T
PIVOT
( 
min(v)
FOR y IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])  
) AS pvt 
ORDER BY x
```

Comment: i AM GETTING `Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 42
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.
`

Comment: It's the order by from your example.  Remove it if it won't compile.  The other option (in SQL Server) is to use TOP 100%

Comment: Sorry... IsNull was put in the wrong spot. I wasn't aware that you had missing data in your pivot results. I also corrected your ORDER BY bug. You were missing the ") AS T" from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used the dynamic pivot technique in this SO question [Simple way to transpose columns and rows in Sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql)

To put NULLs in my pivot report like below. Does get more messy though.

```
CREATE TABLE [MYTABLE]
(
    [A] int
    , [B] int
    , [VAL] float
);

INSERT INTO [MYTABLE] ([A], [B], [VAL]) VALUES
(1, 1, -218.46),
(1, 2, -2.1846000000000e+02),
(2, 1, 6.4000000000000e+01),
(2, 2, -218.46),
(2, 3, 6.4000000000000e+01),
(3, 2, -2.1846000000000e+02),
(3, 3, -218.46),
(4, 3, 6.4000000000000e+01),
(4, 4, -218.46),
(4, 5, 6.4000000000000e+01),
(5, 4, 6.4000000000000e+01),
(5, 5, -218.46),
(5, 6, 6.4000000000000e+01),
(6, 5, 6.4000000000000e+01),
(6, 6, -218.46),
(6, 7, 6.4000000000000e+01),
(7, 6, 6.4000000000000e+01),
(7, 7, -218.46),
(7, 8, 6.4000000000000e+01),
(8, 7, 6.4000000000000e+01),
(8, 8, -218.46),
(8, 9, 6.4000000000000e+01),
(9, 8, 6.4000000000000e+01),
(9, 9, -218.46),
(9, 10, 6.4000000000000e+01),
(10, 9, 6.4000000000000e+01),
(10, 10, -218.46);

DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max), @PvtCols nvarchar(max), @PvtSelect nvarchar(max)

SELECT @PvtSelect = Stuff(
                (
                    SELECT ',IsNull(' + Quotename(B) + ',0) as ' + Quotename(B)
                    FROM MYTABLE mt
                    GROUP BY B
                    ORDER BY B
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                ,1,1,'')

SELECT @PvtCols = Stuff(
                    (
                    SELECT DISTINCT  ',' + Quotename(B) 
                    FROM MYTABLE mt
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                ,1,1,'')

SET @Sql =
'SELECT ' + @PvtSelect + ' 
FROM
(   SELECT  x = a
        ,   y = b
        ,   v = (CASE WHEN IsNumeric(val)=0 THEN 0 ELSE val END)
    FROM    MYTABLE
) AS T
PIVOT
(
    min( v)
    FOR y IN (' + @PvtCols + ') 
) AS pvt
order by x'

EXEC(@SQL)
```