# SQL transpose full table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I need to do the following transpose in MS SQL

from:

```
Day  A  B 
---------
Mon  1  2
Tue  3  4
Wed  5  6
Thu  7  8
Fri  9  0
```

To the following:

```
Value Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri 
--------------------------
A      1   3   5   7   9
B      2   4   6   8   0
```

I understand how to do it with `PIVOT` when there is only one column (A) but I can not figure out how to do it when there are multiple columns to transpose (A,B,...)

Example code to be transposed:

```
select LEFT(datename(dw,datetime),3) as DateWeek, 
  sum(ACalls) as A, 
  Sum(BCalls) as B 
from DataTable
group by LEFT(datename(dw,datetime),3)
```

Table Structure:

```
Column DataType
DateTime Datetime
ACalls int
BCalls int
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple way to transpose columns and rows in Sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In order to transpose the data into the result that you want, you will need to use both the [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) functions.

The `UNPIVOT` function takes the `A` and `B` columns and converts the results into rows.  Then you will use the `PIVOT` function to transform the `day` values into columns:

```
select *
from
(
  select day, col, value
  from yourtable
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (A, B)
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for day in (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58c2c/2).

If you are using SQL Server 2008+, then you can use `CROSS APPLY` with `VALUES` to unpivot the data. You code would be changed to the following:

```
select *
from
(
  select day, col, value
  from yourtable
  cross apply
  (
    values ('A', A),('B', B)
  ) c (col, value)
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for day in (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58c2c/5).

Edit #1, applying your current query into the above solution you will use something similar to this:

```
select *
from
(
  select LEFT(datename(dw,datetime),3) as DateWeek,
    col, 
    value
  from DataTable 
  cross apply 
  (
    values ('A', ACalls), ('B', BCalls)
  ) c (col, value)
) src
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for dateweek in (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri)
) piv
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I can not manage to do the unpivot for the following query: select LEFT(datename(dw,datetime),3) as DateWeek, SUM(ACalls) as A, SUM(BCalls) as B from _online_interval_data group by LEFT(datename(dw,datetime),3) Unpivot (=Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Unpivot')

Comment: I'm using SQL2008 R2. Same problem error with Cross apply --> select LEFT(datename(dw,datetime),3) as DateWeek, SUM(ACalls) as A, 
SUM(BCalls) as B from data 
group by LEFT(datename(dw,datetime),3) cross apply (=Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'cross')

Comment: @user2148939 I don't understand that code that you posted.  Please edit your original post with your table structure and then the code you are using.

Comment: @user2148939 See my edit on how you will incorporate your current query into the solution.

Comment: Yes, yes!! Thanks you!! I guess if you need more columns you then need to add more values values ('A', ACalls), ('B', BCalls), ('C', DCalls),... Correct?

Comment: @user2148939 Yes, that is correct. You will just add more columns in the `VALUES`. :)

Comment: The column 'col' seems to get ordered alplabetcially. How can you change the order descending like C, B, A or other order like A, C, B?

Comment: You will just add an ORDER BY col DESC at the end of the SQL. After the ) piv

Comment: But what about if you want another order. For example, if 'col' are the names of the months. You don't want them ordered like April, August, December,... You want them like January, February, March,... How can you keep this order?

Comment: @Selrac Please post a new question with more details about the issue. It will be easier than going back and forth in the comments. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
with orig as
(
select 'Mon' as day_,   1 as A,  2 as B from dual union all 
select 'Tue',  3,  4 from dual union all 
select 'Wed',  5,  6 from dual union all 
select 'Thu',  7,  8 from dual union all 
select 'Fri',  9,  0 from dual union all 
select 'Sat',  10,  1 from dual union all 
select 'Sun',  11,  5 from dual 
)
, chg1 as
(
select col_, day_, case when col_='A' then A else B end  AorB
from orig cross join (select 'A' col_ from dual union all select 'B' col_ from dual)
)
  
select 
   col_
 , max(case when day_='Mon' then AorB else null end) Mon
 , max(case when day_='Tue' then AorB else null end) Tue
 , max(case when day_='Wed' then AorB else null end) Wed
 , max(case when day_='Thu' then AorB else null end) Thu
 , max(case when day_='Fri' then AorB else null end) Fri
 , max(case when day_='Sat' then AorB else null end) Sat
 , max(case when day_='Sun' then AorB else null end) Sun
from chg1
group by col_
```

Comment: This is a SQL Server question.

Comment: Yep, the above was tested on Oracle only, no idea if it would work on SQL Server

Comment: Well, it doesn't. SQL Server doesn't have `dual`.