# Sql Server Convert all the Rows into Columns and All the Columns into Rows

Tags: sql-server

I am doing a matching between two types of items say X and Y. And at some point the user would like to change the view, Then I have to make Rows as Cols and Cols as Rows.

Is it possible I can change this (example) table, Here 1 shows a matching exist between X and Y.

```
Matching |   X1   |   X2  |   X3 
-------    ------   -----   ------
Y1       |   1    |  0    |    0  
------     ------   ------   ----- 
Y2       |   0    |   0   |    1
------     -----   ------   ------
Y3       |   1    |   1   |    1
```

To This:

```
Matching |   Y1   |   Y2  |   Y3    
-------    ------   -----   ------
 X1      |   1    |   0   |    1  
------     ------   ------   ----- 
 X2      |   0    |   0   |    1
------     -----   ------   ------
 X3      |   0    |   1   |    1
```

I have tried with Pivot but every thing is messed up :( . I don't know what to put in Max().

Here is what I tried so far:

```
SELECT [Matching]
      ,[X1]
      ,[X2]
      ,[X3]

  FROM [Test].[dbo].[Matching_Full]




  Select [Y1] as Y1,
  [Y2] as Y2,
  [Y3] as Y3


  FROM 

  (  Select [Matching]
      ,[X1]
      ,[X2]
      ,[X3]

  FROM [Test].[dbo].[Matching_Full] ) PivotData

  PIVOT

  (
  MAx (Matching)
 FOR Matching IN 

  ([Y1],[Y2],[Y3])

  ) AS Pivoting
```

Comment: This is called `PIVOT`

Comment: And PIVOT is easily search-able on Bing, Google, or whatever you prefer, now that you know what term to search for.  ;-)  Knowing the term to search is usually the hardest thing to figure out, so Hogan gave you the most valuable inf possible.  Too bad he can't get  points for up-voted comments.

Comment: @DavidStratton - I guess.  I'm ok with the rep I have (only 1101 till 30k!)

Comment: @Hogan I have tried with Pivot. But I think with Pivot I need to give some column name in Max(). May be I am wrong but if you know anything please correct me. I also have edit the question

Comment: You want max for each of x1, x2, x3

Comment: @Hogan Yes I think so. If you look at the example table. You can get an idea what I am looking for. And I think that Pivot is not a right solution for this. I could be wrong may be you can give me better suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: You need to unpivot and then pivot see this question --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297809/sql-transpose-full-table that does a full transpose of data

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this might answer your question?

The only problem I can see for this query is that it requires to be updated whenever a new line, let's say `Y4`, for instance, is added.

But, if your table is to have only three lines, this might help, or put you on the track.

```
select Matching, sum(Y1) as Y1, sum(Y2) as Y2, sum(Y3) as Y3
       from (
           select 'X1' as Matching
                  , X1 as Y1
                  , null as Y2
                  , null as Y3
              from Matching
              where Matching like 'Y1'
           union
               select 'X2' as Matching
                     , X2
                     , null
                     , null
                  from Matching
                  where Matching like 'Y1'
           union
               select 'X3' as Matching
                       , X3
                       , null
                       , null
                   from Matching
                   where Matching like 'Y1'
           union
               select 'X1' as Matching
                       , null
                       , X1
                       , null
                   from Matching
                  where Matching like 'Y2'
           union
               select 'X2' as Matching
                       , null
                       , X2
                       , null
                   from Matching
                   where Matching like 'Y2'
           union
               select 'X3' as Matching
                       , null
                       , X3
                       , null
                  from Matching
                  where Matching like 'Y2'         
           union
               select 'X1' as Matching
                       , null
                       , null
                       , X1
                   from Matching
                   where Matching like 'Y3'
           union
               select 'X2' as Matching
                       , null
                       , null
                       , X2
                   from Matching
                   where Matching like 'Y3'
           union
               select 'X3' as Matching
                       , null
                       , null
                       , X3
                   from Matching
                   where Matching like 'Y3'         
        ) x
    group by Matching
```

I remember having such things in the past, about five or six years ago for tables that could have variable number of lines, and I can't seem to remember correctly. One thing is for sure though, I was doing something alike.

The result will be as stated in your question.