# Where IN a Comma delimited string

Tags: sql-server, delimiter, where-in

I would like to retrieve certain users from a full list of a temp table #temptable.
The query looks like this:

```
DECLARE @List varchar(max)
SELECT @List = coalesce(@List + ',','') + '''' + StaffCode + ''''
FROM tblStaffs

SELECT UserName
FROM #temptable
WHERE #temptable.StaffCode IN (@List)
```

I can tell @List is in a right format:

```
'AAA','ABB','BBB','CCC','DDD','MMM'
```

And if I change it to

```
WHERE #temptable.StaffCode IN ('AAA','ABB','BBB','CCC','DDD','MMM')
```

It certainly works, then why not IN (@List)?

Comment: It would not work for `in ('''AAA'',''BBB''')` which is really what is happening; I believe you'll need to parse @List into a small temp table and join against it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. This is really what I want to know. And one way to solve this problem is to use dynamic sql as answered by Eric from previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create some split string function and convert the comma separated values to rows then you can use the converted rows `IN` clause

```
DECLARE @List VARCHAR(max)

SELECT @List = COALESCE(@List + ',', '') +StaffCode
FROM   tblStaffs

SELECT UserName
FROM   #temptable
WHERE  #temptable.StaffCode IN (SELECT split_values
                                FROM   dbo.Splitstring_function(@list))
```

Check [***here***](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) for various Split String function

If you dont want to create functions then you can also directly use the code instead of creating a new function(**M.Ali's** answer).

Another way of doing it is using `dynamic query`.

```
Declare @List varchar(max), @sql nvarchar(max)

Select @List = coalesce(@List + ',','') + '''' + StaffCode + ''''
From tblStaffs

set @sql = '
Select UserName
From #temptable
Where #temptable.StaffCode IN ('+ @List + ')'

--print @sql
exec (@sql)
```

To debug the dynamic query always `print` the dynamic sql before executing.

Comment: @Zerubbabel - Its just a example you need to create a split string function. I have given you a link also from there you can create a split string function.

Answer (score 5):

Because the Variable has a string which IN operator reads as `'AAA'',''ABB'',''BBB'` and it treats it as a single value.

In your query you should really use the query itself in the `IN` operator something like....

```
Select UserName
From #temptable
Where #temptable.StaffCode IN (SELECT StaffCode From tblStaffs)
```

Anyway if there is a need to use variable and then read values inside the `IN` operator from that variable you can do something like this....

```
DECLARE @List VARCHAR(1000);

Select @List = coalesce(@List + ',','') + StaffCode 
From tblStaffs


SELECT *
From #temptable
Where #temptable.StaffCode IN (
     SELECT t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)')
           FROM (
                 SELECT x = CAST('<t>' + 
                  REPLACE(@List , ',', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
                ) a
     CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/t') t(c))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you not use a comma-delimited string at all. Consider a [semi-join](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/07/19/671712.aspx) instead:

```
select [Temp].[UserName] 
from 
    #temptable [Temp]
where
    exists (select 1 from [tblStaffs] where [tblStaffs].[StaffCode] = [Temp].[StaffCode]);
```

Comment: What if the @List is an sproc or function parameter?

Comment: @GlassCannon I only made this suggestion because the example in the OP did not have `@List` as a sproc parameter, but as something declared and populated immediately before it was used. If it _were_ a sproc parameter, and if it were permissible to change the signature of the sproc, then I would suggest a table-valued parameter rather than a comma-delimited string. If for whatever reason the sproc's parameters cannot be modified, then (and only then) would I consider a string-splitting function as described in the accepted answer.