# How to solve error while trying SQL dynamic unpivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Could you please kindly help to take a look at my error?

Original Table:

[image]

Target Table:

[image]

Use below code:

```
Select DATE,cities,sales
From Test
UNPIVOT
( sales
For cities in (city1, city2, city3)
) AS XYZ
```

and the result is successful.

However, the city list might grow into city4, city5...
So I was trying to use dynamic unpivot to achieve this

Code:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
select @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',', '') + quotename(COLUMN_NAME)
From (  Select column_name
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_name = 'Test'
        AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'Date' ) AS FiledList
Select DATE,cities,sales
From Test
UNPIVOT
( sales
For cities in (@cols)
) AS XYZ
```

[image]

There seems to be an error, and tried a couple ways, not working.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, already edited.

Comment: You need to form the pivot query dynamically and execute with `sp_executesql` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 Do a search there are lots of similar example in SO

Comment: I asked a similar question years ago https://stackoverflow.com/q/30512646/4271117. You need to use dynamic SQL. the @cols you have is a plain string, and therefore the error. [Duplicate of many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function) :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider changing the database so that it is pivoted in the first place. A table with Date, City and Sales would lend itself better to the addition of cities and negate the need for the un-pivot in the first place, assuming you're doing this enable aggregation. Otherwise, you'll need to dynamically create the SQL, which is far from ideal.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DATE,cities,sales
From Test
UNPIVOT
( sales
For cities in (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(city) FROM cities)
) AS XYZ
```