# convert columns to rows using pivot

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to convert cols to rows to fit the format in the image
This is my query:

```
Select dt1.Year,dt1.oneyearret as '1-Year Retention',dt2.twoyearret as '2-Year Retention',dt4.fouryeargrad as '4-Year Graduation Rate',dt5.fiveyeargrad as '5-Year Graduation Rate',dt6.sixyeargrad as '6-Year Graduation Rate' from
(select case WHEN (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all,1,4))) ='2015' then '2015' WHEN (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all,1,4))) ='2016' then '2016' else (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all,1,4)))  end  as 'Year',
                                  cast(convert(varchar,(Convert(Money,SUM(rg.RET1_FF),1)/Convert(Money,SUM(rg.COHORT_COUNT),1))*100,1) as numeric(10,1)) as oneyearret         
                                  from vw_Retention_Graduation_F rg
                                  inner join dim_Time t
                                  on rg.TIME_KEY = t.TIME_KEY
                                  inner join dim_Part_Full pf
                                  on rg.PART_FULL_KEY=pf.PART_FULL_KEY
                                  inner join dim_Student_Level sl
                                  on rg.STUDENT_LEVEL_KEY=SL.STUDENT_LEVEL_KEY
                                  inner join dim_Student_Population sp
                                  on rg.STUDENT_POPULATION_KEY=sp.STUDENT_POPULATION_KEY
                                  inner join dim_College c
                                  on rg.COLLEGE_KEY = c.COLLEGE_KEY
                                  WHERE t.ACADEMIC_PERIOD between 201527 and 201627
                                  AND pf.PART_FULL = 'F'
                                  AND sl.STUDENT_LEVEL = 'UG'
                                  AND sp.STUDENT_POPULATION = 'N'
                                  GROUP BY (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all,1,4)) ) ) dt1 inner join
(select case WHEN (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all,1,4))) ='2014' then '2015' WHEN (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all,1,4))) ='2015' then '2016' else (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all,1,4)))  end  as 'Year',
                                  cast(convert(varchar,(Convert(Money,SUM(rg.RET2_FF),1)/Convert(Money,SUM(rg.COHORT_COUNT),1))*100,1) as numeric(10,1)) as twoyearret         
                                  from vw_Retention_Graduation_F rg
                                  inner join dim_Time t
                                  on rg.TIME_KEY = t.TIME_KEY
                                  inner join dim_Part_Full pf
                                  on rg.PART_FULL_KEY=pf.PART_FULL_KEY
                                  inner join dim_Student_Level sl
                                  on rg.STUDENT_LEVEL_KEY=SL.STUDENT_LEVEL_KEY
                                  inner join dim_Student_Population sp
                                  on rg.STUDENT_POPULATION_KEY=sp.STUDENT_POPULATION_KEY
                                  inner join dim_College c
                                  on rg.COLLEGE_KEY = c.COLLEGE_KEY
                                  WHERE t.ACADEMIC_PERIOD between 201427 and 201527
                                  AND pf.PART_FULL = 'F'
                                  AND sl.STUDENT_LEVEL = 'UG'
                                  AND sp.STUDENT_POPULATION = 'N'
                                  GROUP BY (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all,1,4)) ) ) dt2 on dt1.Year = dt2.year
                                  inner join
(select case WHEN (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all,1,4))) ='2012' then '2015' WHEN (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all,1,4))) ='2013' then '2016' else (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all,1,4)))  end  as 'Year',
                                  cast(convert(varchar,(Convert(Money,SUM(rg.GRAD4_FF),1)/Convert(Money,SUM(rg.COHORT_COUNT),1))*100,1) as numeric(10,1)) as fouryeargrad         
                                  from vw_Retention_Graduation_F rg
                                  inner join dim_Time t
                                  on rg.TIME_KEY = t.TIME_KEY
                                  inner join dim_Part_Full pf
                                  on rg.PART_FULL_KEY=pf.PART_FULL_KEY
                                  inner join dim_Student_Level sl
                                  on rg.STUDENT_LEVEL_KEY=SL.STUDENT_LEVEL_KEY
                                  inner join dim_Student_Population sp
                                  on rg.STUDENT_POPULATION_KEY=sp.STUDENT_POPULATION_KEY
                                  inner join dim_College c
                                  on rg.COLLEGE_KEY = c.COLLEGE_KEY
                                  WHERE t.ACADEMIC_PERIOD between 201227 and 201327
                                  AND pf.PART_FULL = 'F'
                                  AND sl.STUDENT_LEVEL = 'UG'
                                  AND sp.STUDENT_POPULATION = 'N'
                                  GROUP BY (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all,1,4)) ) ) dt4 on dt2.Year = dt4.year
                                  inner join
(select case WHEN (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all,1,4))) ='2011' then '2015' WHEN (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all,1,4))) ='2012' then '2016' else (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all,1,4)))  end  as 'Year',
                                  cast(convert(varchar,(Convert(Money,SUM(rg.GRAD5_FF),1)/Convert(Money,SUM(rg.COHORT_COUNT),1))*100,1) as numeric(10,1)) as fiveyeargrad        
                                  from vw_Retention_Graduation_F rg
                                  inner join dim_Time t
                                  on rg.TIME_KEY = t.TIME_KEY
                                  inner join dim_Part_Full pf
                                  on rg.PART_FULL_KEY=pf.PART_FULL_KEY
                                  inner join dim_Student_Level sl
                                  on rg.STUDENT_LEVEL_KEY=SL.STUDENT_LEVEL_KEY
                                  inner join dim_Student_Population sp
                                  on rg.STUDENT_POPULATION_KEY=sp.STUDENT_POPULATION_KEY
                                  inner join dim_College c
                                  on rg.COLLEGE_KEY = c.COLLEGE_KEY
                                  WHERE t.ACADEMIC_PERIOD between 201127 and 201227
                                  AND pf.PART_FULL = 'F'
                                  AND sl.STUDENT_LEVEL = 'UG'
                                  AND sp.STUDENT_POPULATION = 'N'
                                  GROUP BY (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all,1,4)) ) ) dt5 on dt4.Year = dt5.year
                                  inner join
(select case WHEN (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all,1,4))) ='2010' then '2015' WHEN (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all,1,4))) ='2011' then '2016' else (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all,1,4)))  end  as 'Year',
                                  cast(convert(varchar,(Convert(Money,SUM(rg.GRAD6_FF),1)/Convert(Money,SUM(rg.COHORT_COUNT),1))*100,1) as numeric(10,1)) as sixyeargrad         
                                  from vw_Retention_Graduation_F rg
                                  inner join dim_Time t
                                  on rg.TIME_KEY = t.TIME_KEY
                                  inner join dim_Part_Full pf
                                  on rg.PART_FULL_KEY=pf.PART_FULL_KEY
                                  inner join dim_Student_Level sl
                                  on rg.STUDENT_LEVEL_KEY=SL.STUDENT_LEVEL_KEY
                                  inner join dim_Student_Population sp
                                  on rg.STUDENT_POPULATION_KEY=sp.STUDENT_POPULATION_KEY
                                  inner join dim_College c
                                  on rg.COLLEGE_KEY = c.COLLEGE_KEY
                                  WHERE t.ACADEMIC_PERIOD between 201027 and 201127
                                  AND pf.PART_FULL = 'F'
                                  AND sl.STUDENT_LEVEL = 'UG'
                                  AND sp.STUDENT_POPULATION = 'N'
                                  GROUP BY (CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(ACADEMIC_PERIOD_all,1,4)) ) )  dt6 on dt5.Year = dt6.year
```

Current Output:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Required Output:
[image: ![https://i.stack.imgur.com/FID9g.png]

Comment: Wow that query is seriously ugly. Some formatting would turn that wall of text into something that doesn't make others want to kill themselves.

Comment: if you can read it good or else dont bother.

Comment: So I help you format your post and you tell me to not bother. That is not a great attitude to present to people who are trying to help you.

Comment: Maybe this is of some help to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297809/sql-transpose-full-table ?

Comment: Oh I have a feeling not many will bother, especially those of the likes of @SeanLange and I.

Answer (score 1):

After replacing your lengthy SQL code with a shorter one, simply producing your sample data, the actual "transpose" action can be achieved with something like this:

```
create table tbl (yr int, y1ret float, y2ret float, y4grad float, y5grad float, y6grad float);
insert into tbl VALUES (2015, 83.5, 71.4, 34.8, 54.7, 59.9 ), (2016, 83.6, 73.8, 33.8, 53.6, 60);

select * from (
  select yr, col, value
  from tbl
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (y1ret, y2ret, y4grad, y5grad, y6grad)
  ) unpiv

) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for yr in ([2015], [2016])
) piv
```

This is of course an adaptation of the original solution presented here: [SQL transpose full table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297809/sql-transpose-full-table)
A running demo can be found here: http://rextester.com/CNYR30557

In most applications it is simpler and faster to do this kind of manipulation in the receiving environment, i.e. either in the back-end using PHP or in the front-end using JavaScript.

**Edit**:

To accommodate your lengthy SQL code into this you could do:

```
;WITH tbl AS ( -- YOUR CODE GOES HERE --
)
select * from (
  select yr, col, value
  from tbl
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (y1ret, y2ret, y4grad, y5grad, y6grad)
  ) unpiv

) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for yr in ([2015], [2016])
) piv
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but i dont have permission to create a table.

Comment: You dont need to create the table. That was merely a placeholder. If you put your code into a "Common Table Expression" then you can run the whole thing from there. A "CTE" behaves just like a view or a table.

Comment: Ahh gotit! thanks a ton!

Comment: what does col and value represent here?

Comment: They are names you can choose for yourself and are part of the `unpivot` clause. You need to generate this intermediate format first before you can stitch it together again with `pivot`, see here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055902/unpivot-with-column-name

Comment: i should create the names col yr and value before in my query and then use them in unpivot?

Comment: i got the output! thanks a lot!!