# Split serial column into parallel columns for each value

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with several columns:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
[ValueID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[RealValue] [float] NOT NULL
) ON PRIMARY

+---------+----------------------+----------+
| ValueID | Timestamp            |RealValue |
+---------+----------------------+----------+
| 123     | 3/1/2018 12:00:49 AM | 54.1     |
| 123     | 3/1/2018 12:01:49 AM | 55.1     |
| 123     | 3/1/2018 12:02:49 AM | 56.1     |
| 123     | 3/1/2018 12:03:49 AM | 57.1     |
| 123     | 3/1/2018 12:04:49 AM | 58.1     |
| 876     | 3/1/2018 12:00:49 AM | 1.0      |
| 876     | 3/1/2018 12:01:49 AM | 1.1      |
| 876     | 3/1/2018 12:02:49 AM | 1.2      |
| 876     | 3/1/2018 12:03:49 AM | 1.3      |
| 876     | 3/1/2018 12:04:49 AM | 1.4      |
| 63      | 3/1/2018 12:00:49 AM | 300.0    |
| 63      | 3/1/2018 12:01:49 AM | 300.5    |
| 63      | 3/1/2018 12:02:49 AM | 301.0    |
| 63      | 3/1/2018 12:03:49 AM | 301.5    |
| 63      | 3/1/2018 12:04:49 AM | 302.0    |
+---------+----------------------+----------+
```

I need to split this table into a "column-per-value" structure:

```
+----------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| Timestamp            | 123      | 876      | 63       |
+----------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 3/1/2018 12:00:49 AM | 54.1     | 1.0      | 300.0    |
| 3/1/2018 12:01:49 AM | 55.1     | 1.1      | 300.5    |
| 3/1/2018 12:02:49 AM | 56.1     | 1.2      | 301.0    |
| 3/1/2018 12:03:49 AM | 57.1     | 1.3      | 301.5    |
| 3/1/2018 12:04:49 AM | 58.1     | 1.4      | 302.0    |
+----------------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Would this be possible with SQL, or is it more suited to a script?

Such as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [ValueID] FROM [db].[dbo].[MyTable]

//  ...Build a hash of distinct values in the script...

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NewTable](
[123] int NOT NULL,
[876] int NOT NULL,
[63] int NOT NULL
...
) ON PRIMARY

//  ...Loop through hash and populate each column with a separate query...
```

The table is fairly large (26 million rows) and there are ~500 distinct `[ValueID]` values which would become columns in the destination table.

Comment: [SQL transpose fullt table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297809/sql-transpose-full-table) looks similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL transpose full table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297809/sql-transpose-full-table)

Comment: Da, da-da-daaaa...! [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms177410(v=sql.105)) to the rescue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `pivot` statement.

### 1. Static version

If you have a fixed number of `ValueID` values you can write a query like this (otherwise you should use a dynamic solution to produce all output columns):

```
if OBJECT_ID('MyTable') is null
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [ValueID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [RealValue] [float] NOT NULL
  )  
insert into [dbo].[MyTable]
          select 123     ,'20180301 12:00:49',54.1      
union all select 123     ,'20180301 12:01:49',55.1      
union all select 123     ,'20180301 12:02:49',56.1      
union all select 123     ,'20180301 12:03:49',57.1      
union all select 123     ,'20180301 12:04:49',58.1      
union all select 876     ,'20180301 12:00:49',1.0       
union all select 876     ,'20180301 12:01:49',1.1       
union all select 876     ,'20180301 12:02:49',1.2       
union all select 876     ,'20180301 12:03:49',1.3       
union all select 876     ,'20180301 12:04:49',1.4       
union all select 63      ,'20180301 12:00:49',300.0     
union all select 63      ,'20180301 12:01:49',300.5     
union all select 63      ,'20180301 12:02:49',301.0     
union all select 63      ,'20180301 12:03:49',301.5     
union all select 63      ,'20180301 12:04:49',302.0     

select piv.*
from 
( 
select ValueID,Timestamp,RealValue
from [dbo].[MyTable] 
) src 
pivot 
( 
max(realValue) 
for valueid in ([123], [876], [63])  -- If you have other valueids add them here
) piv
```

Results of this query:

[image]

### 2. Dynamic version

If you need a dynamic query that automatically create all the columns for all `ValueId` values you can use dynamic SQL, but be aware of security problems (SQL injection etc) of this approach!

Here is a sample script that dynamically generates a query with all the columns for your `ValueID`:

```
if OBJECT_ID('MyTableDyn') is null
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTableDyn](
    [ValueID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [RealValue] [float] NOT NULL
  )  
insert into [dbo].[MyTableDyn]
          select 123     ,'20180301 12:00:49',54.1      
union all select 123     ,'20180301 12:01:49',55.1      
union all select 123     ,'20180301 12:02:49',56.1      
union all select 123     ,'20180301 12:03:49',57.1      
union all select 123     ,'20180301 12:04:49',58.1      
union all select 876     ,'20180301 12:00:49',1.0       
union all select 876     ,'20180301 12:01:49',1.1       
union all select 876     ,'20180301 12:02:49',1.2       
union all select 876     ,'20180301 12:03:49',1.3       
union all select 876     ,'20180301 12:04:49',1.4       
union all select 63      ,'20180301 12:00:49',300.0     
union all select 63      ,'20180301 12:01:49',300.5     
union all select 63      ,'20180301 12:02:49',301.0     
union all select 63      ,'20180301 12:03:49',301.5     
union all select 63      ,'20180301 12:04:49',302.0     
union all select 99      ,'20180301 12:00:49',900.0     
union all select 99      ,'20180301 12:01:49',900.5     
union all select 99      ,'20180301 12:02:49',901.0     
union all select 99      ,'20180301 12:03:49',901.5     
union all select 99      ,'20180301 12:04:49',902.0  

declare @script nvarchar(max)=''
declare @ids nvarchar(max)=''
select @ids = @ids + ', ['+ cast([ValueID] as varchar(max)) + ']' 
  from [dbo].[MyTableDyn] 
  group by [ValueID]
set @ids = RIGHT(@ids, len(@ids)-2)

set @script = @script + 'select piv.*'
set @script = @script + ' from' 
set @script = @script + ' ( '
set @script = @script + ' select ValueID,Timestamp,RealValue'
set @script = @script + ' from [dbo].[MyTableDyn] '
set @script = @script + ' ) src '
set @script = @script + ' pivot '
set @script = @script + ' (' 
set @script = @script + ' max(realValue) '
set @script = @script + ' for valueid in (' + @ids +') '
set @script = @script + ' ) piv '

exec (@script)
```

Here are the results (as you can see a new column with id 99 appears):

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this dynamic solution is perfect.