# Need two rows after join from single row based on two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table1 with three columns and a table2 with single column.

If the value of first column is Y then I need a particular value from table 2 as a row in another table after join and if the second column is Y then I need a particular value from table 2 as another row in 3rd table after join. There is no common column in both the tables.

If two columns are in a row have Y as value then I need two rows in the final table  after join. I'm using case right now for joining, but only one column is getting checked.

Can someone help me with this?

```
       table1                       
--------------------         
col1   col2  col3(pk)             
--------------------         
y       n     123                  
y       y     456


   table2                     
--------------------         
    col1               
--------------------         
    col1Y
    col2Y
```

Expected output

```
   table1                      
--------------------         
col1   col2             
--------------------         
 123   col1Y
 456   col1Y
 456   col2Y
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide (1) sample data; (2) desired results; (3) a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: provided the sample data

Comment: I can't figure out how you get that expected result... Explain!

Answer (score 0):

```
select col3 as col1, 'col1y' as col2 from myTable where col1 = 'y'
union
select col3 as col1, 'col2y' as col2 from myTable where col2 = 'y'
--order by col1, col2;
```

[SQLFiddle sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/167a0/3)

Answer (score 0):

you also can check how to transpose tables with pivot command

[SQL transpose full table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297809/sql-transpose-full-table)

Answer (score 0):

We can `unpivot` and `join` to get the results you're looking for:

```
declare @table1 table (col1 char(1),col2 char(1),col3 int)
insert into @table1(col1,col2,col3) values
('y','n',123)        ,   
('y','y',456)
declare @table2 table (col1 char(5))
insert into @table2 (col1) values
('col1Y'),('col2Y')

select
    u.col3 as col2,t2.col1 as col2
from
    @table1 t1
        unpivot
    (cval for cname in (col1,col2)) u
        cross apply
    (select cname + cval as Complete) v
        inner join
    @table2 t2
        on
            v.complete = t2.col1
```

Result:

```
col1        col2
----------- -----
123         col1Y
456         col1Y
456         col2Y
```

But after the `unpivot` and `cross apply`, we didn't really *need* `table2` at all (we could have just filtered down to rows where `cval` is `Y`). But for now I've included it in case I'm missing something or there's more to build up in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need table2 but here is where you could do it with case statement.

```
SELECT col1, col2 from (
  SELECT 
CASE col1
  WHEN 'y' THEN col3
  ELSE 'null'
END AS col1,
CASE col1
  WHEN 'y' THEN 'col1Y'
  ELSE 'null'
END AS col2
from table1 as tbl1

union all

select
CASE col2
  WHEN 'y' THEN col3
  ELSE 'null'
END AS col1,
CASE col2
  WHEN 'y' THEN 'col2Y'
  ELSE 'null'
END AS col2
FROM table1 as tbl2) as tbl
where tbl.col1 <> 'null';
```

[SQL Fiddle Sample](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86d4f4/25)