# table a value to create table b column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

lets say i have table a with 2 column that have hundres of value
the code value
table A

| code | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | lorem |
| 4 | ipsum |
| ... | ... |
| 102 | dolar |

table B

| id | 1 | 4 | ... | 102 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val | val | val | val | val |

how can i do this process, without writing every single value on table a as new column on table b?

Comment: Google for "SQL pivot table" or "SQL cross tab"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL transpose full table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297809/sql-transpose-full-table)

Comment: @Chobo thanks for the reply, it will if i have like dozen of column, i have hundres column

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to mark this as a duplicate, but this thread answers your question:

[SQL transpose full table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297809/sql-transpose-full-table)