# Displaying Columns as Rows in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, pivot

I have read dozens of solutions to similar transposition problems as the one I am about to propose but oddly none that exactly mirrors my issue. I am simply trying to flip my rows to columns in a simple dashboard type data set.

The data when pulled from various transaction tables looks like this:

```
DatePeriod  PeriodNumberOverall   Transactions   Customers   Visits

'Jan 2012'   1                    100            50          150
'Feb 2012'   2                    200            100         300
'Mar 2012'   3                    300            200         600
```

and I want to be able to generate the following:

```
                      Jan 2012   Feb 2012   Mar 2012

Transactions          100        200        300
Customers             50         100        200
Visits                150        300        600
```

The metrics will be static (Transactions, Customers and Visits), but the date periods will be dynamic (IE - more added as months go by).

Again, I have ready many examples leveraging pivot, unpivot, store procedures, UNION ALLs, etc, but nothing where I am not doing any aggregating, just literally transposing the whole output. I have also found an easy way to do this in Visual Studio 2005 using a matrix with an embedded list, but I can't export the final output to excel which is a requirement. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check Dynamic Pivot Version in Bluefeet's answert at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the result that you want you need to first `UNPIVOT` the data and then `PIVOT the`DatePeriod` Values.

The UNPIVOT will transform the multiple columns of `Transactions`, `Customers` and `Visits` into multiple rows.  The other answers are using a `UNION ALL` to unpivot but SQL Server 2005 was the first year the `UNPIVOT` function was supported.

The query to unpivot the data is:

```
select dateperiod,
  col, value
from transactions
unpivot
(
  value for col in (Transactions, Customers, Visits)
) u
```

See [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9fd6a/15). This transforms your current columns into multiple rows, so the data looks like the following:

```
| DATEPERIOD |          COL | VALUE |
-------------------------------------
|   Jan 2012 | Transactions |   100 |
|   Jan 2012 |    Customers |    50 |
|   Jan 2012 |       Visits |   150 |
|   Feb 2012 | Transactions |   200 |
```

Now, since the data is in rows, you can apply the `PIVOT` function to the `DatePeriod` column:

```
select col, [Jan 2012], [Feb 2012], [Mar 2012]
from
(
  select dateperiod,
    t.col, value, c.SortOrder
  from
  (
    select dateperiod,
      col, value
    from transactions
    unpivot
    (
      value for col in (Transactions, Customers, Visits)
    ) u
  ) t
  inner join
  (
    select 'Transactions' col, 1 SortOrder
    union all
    select 'Customers' col, 2 SortOrder
    union all
    select 'Visits' col, 3 SortOrder
   ) c
    on t.col = c.col
) d
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for dateperiod in ([Jan 2012], [Feb 2012], [Mar 2012])
) piv
order by SortOrder;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9fd6a/9).

If you have an unknown number of date period's then you will use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(dateperiod) 
                    from transactions
                    group by dateperiod, PeriodNumberOverall
                    order by PeriodNumberOverall
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT col, ' + @cols + ' 
             from 
             (
                select dateperiod,
                  t.col, value, c.SortOrder
                from
                (
                  select dateperiod,
                    col, value
                  from transactions
                  unpivot
                  (
                    value for col in (Transactions, Customers, Visits)
                  ) u
                ) t
                inner join
                (
                  select ''Transactions'' col, 1 SortOrder
                  union all
                  select ''Customers'' col, 2 SortOrder
                  union all
                  select ''Visits'' col, 3 SortOrder
                 ) c
                  on t.col = c.col
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(value)
                for dateperiod in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            order by SortOrder'

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9fd6a/16). Both will give the result:

```
|          COL | JAN 2012 | FEB 2012 | MAR 2012 |
-------------------------------------------------
| Transactions |      100 |      200 |      300 |
|    Customers |       50 |      100 |      200 |
|       Visits |      150 |      300 |      600 |
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the awesome answers!  The only question I have that remains is there any easy way to order the metrics how I want them?  In all three answers the metrics got reordered in alpha order.  Thanks again!

Comment: @user2234794 See my edit, I updated my answer to include an ordering my the columns initial positions

Comment: Thank you for the update.  The main "table" I will be using to transpose for my dashboard will not be a part of the schema - it will be data elements (aggregated metrics/fields) pulled from multiple other tables) into a temp table.  Is there another way to do the ordering if I am not pulling my fields from a single table that exists in my schema?  Apologies if the question is simple/basic - I am not a T-SQL expert by any measure.

Comment: @user2234794 Yes, you can join on a derived table containing a sortorder. See my edit

Answer (score 2):

You need to dynamically create a SQL statement with [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operators on the fly and then run that command. If your metrics static(Transactions, Customers and Visits), hence we can use CROSS APPLY operator with VALUES As a Table Source.

**For SQL Server2008+**

```
DECLARE @cols nvarchar( max),
        @query nvarchar(max)
SELECT @cols =
  STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(t.DatePeriod) AS ColName                               
         FROM dbo.test62 t                   
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value ('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')     

SET @query =
 'SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT t.DatePeriod, COALESCE(o.Transactions, o.Customers, o.Visits) AS PvtVals, o.PvtColumns, o.OrderColumns 
        FROM dbo.test62 t CROSS APPLY (
                                       VALUES(t.Transactions, NULL, NULL, ''Transaction'', 1),
                                             (NULL, t.Customers, NULL, ''Customers'', 2),
                                             (NULL, NULL, t.Visits, ''Visits'', 3)
                                       ) o (Transactions, Customers, Visits, PvtColumns, OrderColumns)
        ) p
  PIVOT
   (      
    MAX(PvtVals) FOR DatePeriod IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) AS pvt
  ORDER BY pvt.OrderColumns '
EXEC(@query)
```

Result:

```
PvtColumns  Jan 2012 Fed 2012 Mar 2012
Transaction 100      200      300
Customers   50       100      200
Visits      150      300      600
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eeef0/2)

**For SQL Server 2005**

```
DECLARE @cols nvarchar( max),
        @query nvarchar(max)
SELECT @cols =
  STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(t.DatePeriod) AS ColName                               
         FROM dbo.test62 t                   
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value ('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')     

SET @query =
 'SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT t.DatePeriod, COALESCE(o.Transactions, o.Customers, o.Visits) AS PvtVals, o.PvtColumns, o.OrderColumns
        FROM dbo.test62 t CROSS APPLY (
                                       SELECT t.Transactions, NULL, NULL, ''Transaction'', 1
                                       UNION ALL 
                                       SELECT NULL, t.Customers, NULL, ''Customers'', 2
                                       UNION ALL 
                                       SELECT NULL, NULL, t.Visits, ''Visits'', 3
                                       ) o (Transactions, Customers, Visits, PvtColumns, OrderColumns)
        ) p
  PIVOT
   (      
    MAX(PvtVals) FOR DatePeriod IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) AS pvt
  ORDER BY pvt.OrderColumns'
EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: `CROSS APPLY ... VALUES` doesn't work in 2005. You can use `CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.Transactions, NULL, NULL, ''Transaction'' UNION ALL SELECT NULL, t.Customers, NULL, ''Customers'' UNION ALL ... )` though

Comment: Thanks Martin for a clarifications!;)Answer updated. BTW, If use CROSS APPLY (SELECT Transactions, Customers, Visits, PvtColumns FROM (VALUES (t.Transactions, NULL, NULL, ''Transaction''), (NULL, t.Customers, NULL, ''Customers''), (NULL, NULL, t.Visits, ''Visits'')) x(Transactions, Customers, Visits, PvtColumns)) o ... it will work?

Comment: Thanks so much for the awesome answers!  The only question I have that remains is there any easy way to order the metrics how I want them?  In all three answers the metrics got reordered in alpha order.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you can know how many different date period in advance, then you can use fixed query like following:

```
;with CTE_UNIONTable
as 
(
select [DatePeriod],[PeriodNumberOverall],[Transactions] as [value], 'Transactions' as subType from table1
UNION ALL 
select [DatePeriod],[PeriodNumberOverall],[Customers] as [value], 'Customers' as subType from table1
UNION ALL 
select [DatePeriod],[PeriodNumberOverall],[Visits] as [value], 'Visits' as subType from table1
), CTE_MiddleResult
as 
(
select * from CTE_UNIONTable
    pivot 
    (
       max(value) 
       for DatePeriod in ([Jan 2012],[Feb 2012],[Mar 2012])
     ) as P
     )
select SubType, max([Jan 2012]) as [Jan 2012] ,max([Feb 2012]) as [Feb 2012], max([Mar 2012]) as [Feb 2012]
from CTE_MiddleResult
group by SubType
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/80f1e/1)**
If how many date period is unpredictable, then @Alexander already gave the solution, the following code is just a second opinion, instead of using **APPLY**, using **UNION ALL**

```
DECLARE @cols nvarchar( max),
        @query nvarchar (max),
        @selective nvarchar(max)
SELECT @cols =
  STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(t.DatePeriod) AS ColName                               
         FROM table1 t                   
         FOR XML PATH( ''), TYPE).value ('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')

SELECT @selective =
  STUFF((SELECT ',MAX(' + QUOTENAME(t.DatePeriod) +') as ' + QUOTENAME(t.DatePeriod)  AS ColName                               
         FROM table1 t                   
         FOR XML PATH( ''), TYPE).value ('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')

set @query = '
;with CTE_UNIONTable
as 
(
select [DatePeriod],[PeriodNumberOverall],[Transactions] as [value], ''Transactions'' as subType from table1
UNION ALL 
select [DatePeriod],[PeriodNumberOverall],[Customers] as [value], ''Customers'' as subType from table1
UNION ALL 
select [DatePeriod],[PeriodNumberOverall],[Visits] as [value], ''Visits'' as subType from table1
), CTE_MiddleResult
as 
(
select * from CTE_UNIONTable
    pivot 
    (
       max(value) 
       for DatePeriod in ('+@cols+')
     ) as P
)
select SubType,' + @selective + ' 
from CTE_MiddleResult
group by SubType'

exec(@query)
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e5871/1)**

Comment: Thanks so much for the awesome answers!  The only question I have that remains is there any easy way to order the metrics how I want them?  In all three answers the metrics got reordered in alpha order.  Thanks again!

Comment: You can add ORDER BY in the end, but either asc or desc, what exact order do you want, maybe the code needs to update a little bit basing on the order you want.