# Pivot in sql for multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table as following:

[image]

Using `pivot` I need the following output:

[image]

The query should not use `Union` set operator.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111418/sql-server-transpose-rows-to-columns

You're looking for Transpose from Rows -> Columns.

Comment: I have done it using pivot for individual val1  and val2  and union the results for the final output..  I checked the above link "Evaldas Buinauskas" , but I need my column name in rows.. ie. val1 and val2 in rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could first do `UNPIVOT` to turn data in the following format:

[image]

and then do `PIVOT` by the `Type` column:

[image]

This is full working example:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [CatDes] CHAR(1)
   ,[val1] TINYINT
   ,[val2] TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([CatDes], [val1], [val2])
VALUES ('a', 1 ,2)
      ,('b', 3 ,4)
      ,('c', 5 ,6)
      ,('d', 7 ,8);

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource
UNPIVOT
(
    [Value] FOR [Type] IN ([val1], [val2])
) UNPVT
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Value]) FOR [CatDes] IN ([a], [b], [c], [d])
) PVT
```

Of course, when you are using `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` you should hard-coded the column values. I guess, in your real case, this is not an option, so I will recommend to you to use a dynamic `T-SQL` statement - build the statement as a string and then execute it using `sp_executesql`.