# Excel, SQL - Change select header rows to columns and insert values for each column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I hope someone can help.  I have an excel file with hundreds of items that looks like the below table, that shows the Style's Color/Size and it's QTY levels.  But I need to take the corresponding header Sizes and match it with the Style and Color as well as it's QTY levels.  Then format it into each row and **then copy the Style, color, length and price that corresponds with each columns.**  I have both excel and sql, if one is easier to work with then the other.

**So basically take this:**

```
+--------+----------+--------+-------+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| STYLE# |  COLOR   | LENGTH | Price | Size 00 | Size 0 | Size 2 | Size 4 | Size 6 | Size 8 | Size 10 | Size 12 | Size 14 | Size 16 | Size 18 | Size 20 | Size 22 | Size 24 | Size 26 | Size 28 | Size 30 | Size 32 |
+--------+----------+--------+-------+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    710 | PURPLE   | RL     |   199 |       0 |      0 |      0 |      2 |      5 |      5 |       5 |       4 |       4 |       3 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |
|    710 | DP CORAL | RL     |   199 |       0 |      0 |      2 |      0 |      1 |      2 |       1 |       3 |       1 |       3 |       1 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |
|    720 | RED      | RL     |   225 |       0 |      0 |      1 |      0 |      0 |      0 |       1 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |
|    720 | NAVY     | RL     |   225 |       0 |      0 |      0 |      1 |      0 |      1 |       2 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |
+--------+----------+--------+-------+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

**And turn it into this:**

```
+--------+----------+---------+-----+--------+-------+
| STYLE# |  COLOR   |  Size   | QTY | LENGTH | Price |
+--------+----------+---------+-----+--------+-------+
|    710 | PURPLE   | Size 00 |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | PURPLE   | Size 0  |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | PURPLE   | Size 2  |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | PURPLE   | Size 4  |   2 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | PURPLE   | Size 6  |   5 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | PURPLE   | Size 8  |   5 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | PURPLE   | Size 10 |   5 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | PURPLE   | Size 12 |   4 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | PURPLE   | Size 14 |   4 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | PURPLE   | Size 16 |   3 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | PURPLE   | Size 18 |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | PURPLE   | Size 20 |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | PURPLE   | Size 22 |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | PURPLE   | Size 24 |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | PURPLE   | Size 26 |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | PURPLE   | Size 28 |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | PURPLE   | Size 30 |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | PURPLE   | Size 32 |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | DP CORAL | Size 00 |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | DP CORAL | Size 0  |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | DP CORAL | Size 2  |   2 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | DP CORAL | Size 4  |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | DP CORAL | Size 6  |   1 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | DP CORAL | Size 8  |   2 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | DP CORAL | Size 10 |   1 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | DP CORAL | Size 12 |   3 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | DP CORAL | Size 14 |   1 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | DP CORAL | Size 16 |   3 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | DP CORAL | Size 18 |   1 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | DP CORAL | Size 20 |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | DP CORAL | Size 22 |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | DP CORAL | Size 24 |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | DP CORAL | Size 26 |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | DP CORAL | Size 28 |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | DP CORAL | Size 30 |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | DP CORAL | Size 32 |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    710 | DP CORAL | Size 00 |   0 | RL     |   199 |
|    720 | RED      | Size 0  |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | RED      | Size 2  |   1 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | RED      | Size 4  |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | RED      | Size 6  |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | RED      | Size 8  |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | RED      | Size 10 |   1 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | RED      | Size 12 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | RED      | Size 14 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | RED      | Size 16 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | RED      | Size 18 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | RED      | Size 20 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | RED      | Size 22 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | RED      | Size 24 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | RED      | Size 26 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | RED      | Size 28 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | RED      | Size 30 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | RED      | Size 32 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | NAVY     | Size 00 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | NAVY     | Size 0  |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | NAVY     | Size 2  |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | NAVY     | Size 4  |   1 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | NAVY     | Size 6  |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | NAVY     | Size 8  |   1 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | NAVY     | Size 10 |   2 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | NAVY     | Size 12 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | NAVY     | Size 14 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | NAVY     | Size 16 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | NAVY     | Size 18 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | NAVY     | Size 20 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | NAVY     | Size 22 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | NAVY     | Size 24 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | NAVY     | Size 26 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | NAVY     | Size 28 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | NAVY     | Size 30 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
|    720 | NAVY     | Size 32 |   0 | RL     |   225 |
+--------+----------+---------+-----+--------+-------+
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a [pivot table](http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-a-table-in-mysql/)

Comment: Please note I still need to copy the Style#, Color, Price, and QTY from each row per each size header columns.

Comment: @paqogomez I'm not very good with sql, but this doesn't seem to be a good solution as I would have to 'sum' up all my color and style values.  Which with hundreds of records is going to take forever.

Comment: Forever is a very long time. I doubt it will take that long. "hundreds of records" ?!? I would be worried if there were millions....not hundreds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out what I need by just using excel and joining the color, price, then adding the corresponding size to each qty level with a pipe-delimiter separating each value.  Then transposing it vertically then, using the text to column function in excel to separate everything out.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can do something like this I think(sorry I am a little rusty)..

```
SELECT style, color, size, qty, length price, 
FROM table_name
ORDER BY style DESC, color, size DESC, qty DESC, length, price;
```

Comment: This just orders this by desc order.

Answer (score 0):

**In excel you can do this step (as i think is the fast way) :**

- choose your data to become rows
- copy that data
- right click
- choose paste special and you choose **transpose**

In sql server you can use keyword **Pivot** and **Unpivot**
this link may help you for this :

[Transpose in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql)

Comment: I'm not very good with sql, but this doesn't seem to be a good solution as I would have to 'sum' up all my color and style values.  Which with hundreds of records is going to take forever.