# Query to change vertical to horizontal

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot

I have a table Machine_Mode_Duration:

[image]

I need a query so that it will be displayed as follows:

[image]

Suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Check this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY`.

Assuming that you have exactly 3 modes and that in case of duplicate `(Machine_id, INTERNAL_MODES)` tuples it is okay to sum up their `INTERNAL_MODE_DURATION`:

```
SELECT
    Machine_Id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN INTERNAL_MODES = 1 THEN INTERNAL_MODE_DURATION ELSE 0 END) AS Mode_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN INTERNAL_MODES = 2 THEN INTERNAL_MODE_DURATION ELSE 0 END) AS Mode_2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN INTERNAL_MODES = 3 THEN INTERNAL_MODE_DURATION ELSE 0 END) AS Mode_3
FROM t
GROUP BY
    Machine_Id;
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use `PIVOT` like this

```
SELECT Machine_ID, 
[1] as Mode_1, [2] as Mode_2, [3] as Mode_3 FROM
(SELECT Machine_ID, Internal_Mode_Duration , InternalModes
    FROM Machine_Mode_Duration) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
Sum(Internal_Mode_Duration)
FOR InternalModes IN ([1], [2], [3])
) AS PivotTable;
```

also you can use old fashioned method via `CASE` like the time that there were no `PIVOT` command ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select Machine_Id, 
       case when INTERNAL_MODES = 1 then INTERNAL_MODE_DURATION end as Mode_1,
       case when INTERNAL_MODES = 2 then INTERNAL_MODE_DURATION end as Mode_2,
       case when INTERNAL_MODES = 3 then INTERNAL_MODE_DURATION end as Mode_3
from Machine_Mode_Duration
group by Machine_Id
order by Machine_Id;
```