# Row as column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below  in SQL Server 2008

```
location       LOB               UnitName
----------     ---------         -------------------
Chennai         Health           UnitB
Mumbai          Health           UnitB
Pune            Health           UnitA,UnitB
Chennai         Motor            UnitB
Mumbai          Motor            UnitB
Pune            Motor            UnitB,UnitC
Trivandum       Motor            UnitC
```

And I am expecting the result like below..

```
Location       Health            Motor
---------      --------          --------
Chennai        UnitB             UnitB
Mumbai         UnitB             UnitB
Pune           UnitA,UnitB       UnitB,UnitC
Trivandum                        UnitC
```

I need a query to display like this. Can anyone help me to achieve this??

Comment: We understand you want the solution, but what have you tried?

Comment: I tried this..


SELECT Location, 
LOB

FROM [VW_UnitVIew2]
PIVOT
(  UnitName
   FOR LOB in ()
) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY Location;

Comment: It throws error...Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.

Comment: Have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql

Comment: [Using PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT location,
        ISNULL((SELECT UnitName FROM table_name t1 WHERE t1.location=t.location AND t1.LOB= 'Health'),'') AS Health,
        ISNULL((SELECT UnitName FROM table_name t2 WHERE t2.location=t.location AND t2.LOB= 'Motor'),'') AS Motor
FROM table_name t
```

Comment: We can not say Health and Motor will be the LOB. It would be dynamic. What is the solution for dynamic data?

Comment: oh, i think thay are constant and not dynamic, it was better to explain this in your question, i will think on it ;)

Answer (score 0):

To pivot a table you need to use aggregate function on pivoted values which is missing in code in your comment. In your case you can use `MAX()`

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
    SELECT location, LOB, UnitName
    FROM @t
) AS t
PIVOT(
    MAX(UnitName)
    FOR LOB IN([Health], [Motor])
) AS pivotTable
```

For dynamic columns try the below:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(LOB)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT LOB FROM @t) AS Courses

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 

'SELECT * 
FROM(
    SELECT location, LOB, UnitName
    FROM @t
) AS t
PIVOT(
    MAX(UnitName)
    FOR LOB IN(' + @ColumnName + ')
) AS pivotTable
ORDER BY Location DESC'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Comment: I will work if LOB is Health and Motor. We can't say that this two LOB only it would be dynamic data

Comment: We can not say Health and Motor will be the LOB. It would be dynamic. What is the solution for dynamic data?

Comment: You need to look for dynamic SQL, that is to build the query string and substitute IN clause with the variable containing column names to be pivoted http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest way which i do is this below query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT MAIN.location, ISNULL(HEALTH.UnitName, '') as [HEALTH], ISNULL(Motor.UnitName, '') as [Motor]
    FROM 
    (Select location from unitlocation ) AS MAIN 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT location, UnitName from unitlocation where LOB = 'Health') AS HEALTH ON MAIN.location = HEALTH.location 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT location, UnitName from unitlocation where LOB = 'Motor') AS Motor ON MAIN.location = Motor.location
```

BELOW IS THE WORKING DEMO 
[CLICK HERE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c350a/7)

**DYNAMIC GENERATION**

PLEASE FIND THE WORKING DEMO FOR DYNAMIC COLUMN NAMES:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [LOB] ORDER BY [LOB]) AS RowNbr, 
        LOB,
        UNITNAME
    FROM
        unitlocation
)
SELECT @cols=STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT
            ',' +QUOTENAME([LOB])
        FROM
            CTE
        WHERE
            CTE.RowNbr=1
    FOR XML PATH('')
    )
,1,1,'')


DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)=
N'SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        unitlocation.location,
        unitlocation.LOB,
        unitlocation.UnitName
    FROM
        unitlocation
) AS p
PIVOT
(
    MAX(UnitName)
    FOR LOB IN ('+@cols+')
) AS pvt'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

[WORKING FIDDLE HERE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c350a/18)