# Transpose multiple columns to rows

Tags: sql-server, pivot, transpose, unpivot

I have a following table :

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTranspose](
[ResultA] [int] NULL,
[ResultB] [int] NULL,
     ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Whose result set is

```
     ResultA ResultB ... ResultZ

      1     10

      2     20
```

Desired result required is:

```
   Name       Compare1     Compare2

   ResultA      10            11

   ResultB      22            33
   ...
   ResultZ.
```

I know this needs to be done using STUFF to get all the columns and the use unpivot/pivot but just not able to get it working.

Comment: and this is tagged mysql because...?

Comment: Your create table statement uses SQL Server syntax.  You should tag the question appopriately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql