# How to output columns as rows in a select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table like this

```
Col1     Col2     Col3   Col4
1        2        3      3
2        23       4      7
3        3        12     4
```

And i want output like this

```
Col1    1   2   3
Col2    2   23  3
Col3    3   4   12
Col4    3   7   4
```

I have googled and found some example over pivot in sql to transform rows into columns, but they are based on aggregation of some values in table. I dont have any such values on which i can put aggregation.The actual no of columns are around 30 and are of different datatype Any ideas will be a great help.

Comment: Almost everything is possible ;) You're talking about Unpivot...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql

Comment: This is a de-normalization operation and can only be done on a non-dynamic query for a *fixed* number of rows - is it correct to assume there is *only* three rows? Aggregation is used because normally the rows in such queries are 0..n, for any n, but it has to be mapped 1..z, for some *query-fixed* value of z. You can still use PIVOT and just aggregate over each row individually (making x = AVG(x)) - but the number of rows *must* be fixed.

Comment: there are many rows in actual scenario but not much when use with some foreign key, but it has many columns with different type of  data. i am still trying to sort this using dynamic query operation

Comment: My recommendation would be to *start* with a normalized source (the 2nd form shown) and then convert to the first form when needed. This makes the transformation easier as the column names are trivially identified - this may even eliminate the need for such a transformation. (My first comment should have read 'de-de-normalization', if the columns represent multiplicity.)

Answer (score 1):

I want to say another way rather than using `pivot` or `unpivot`, you can do it with `dynamic sql` also, it **does not matter how many rows or columns the table has**, lets check together:

*Schema:*

```
create table tblSO(Col1  int,   Col2  int,   Col3 int,   Col4 int)
insert into tblSO values
(1,        2,        3,      3),
(2,        23,       4,      7),
(3,        3 ,       12,     4);
```

now with using `row_number` and a `temptable` (or `table variable`) within `dynamic sql` you can achieve the result you want:

```
declare @counter int = 1
declare @counter2 int
set @counter2=(select count(*) from tblSO)

declare @Sql varchar(max)='create table #rotate (colname varchar(20) '
while @counter<=@counter2
begin
    set @Sql=@Sql+', val_'+cast(@counter as varchar)+' int'
    set @counter=@counter+1
end 
set @counter =1
set @Sql=@Sql+');
insert into #rotate(colname) 
values (''Col1''),(''Col2''),(''Col3''),(''Col4'');
'

set @Sql = @Sql + '
create table #cte(col1  int,col2  int,col3 int,col4 int,rn int)
insert into #cte
select col1,col2,col3,col4,
       row_number() over(order by Col1) rn
from tblSO;
'

while @counter<=@counter2
begin
declare @cl varchar(50)=cast(@counter as varchar)
set @Sql=@Sql + '
 update #rotate set val_'+@cl+'= 
    (select col1 from #cte where rn='+@cl+') where colname=''Col1''
 update #rotate set val_'+@cl+'= 
    (select col2 from #cte where rn='+@cl+') where colname=''Col2''
 update #rotate set val_'+@cl+'= 
    (select col3 from #cte where rn='+@cl+') where colname=''Col3''
 update #rotate set val_'+@cl+'= 
    (select col4 from #cte where rn='+@cl+') where colname=''Col4'' '
set @counter=@counter+1
end
set @Sql=@Sql + ' select * from #rotate
                  drop table #rotate
                  drop table #cte'
exec(@Sql)
```

*Output:*

```
Col1    1   2   3
Col2    2   23  3
Col3    3   4   12
Col4    3   7   4
```

Comment: problem is that in actual scenario, the datatype of columns are diffrent i.e. some are varchar, some are bigint and some are decimal(18,2) and bit and date as well

Comment: this method works for them also, just put the varchar values inside two `'`s `''varchar column ''` in the dynamic section, you can give a sample data by sqlfidde