# Row-wise maximum in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, unpivot

I've got a table with a few columns, and for each row I want the maximum:

```
-- Table:
+----+----+----+----+----+
| ID | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |
|  2 | 11 | 10 | 11 |  9 |
|  3 |  3 |  1 |  4 |  1 |
|  4 |  0 |  2 |  1 |  0 |
|  5 |  2 |  7 |  1 |  8 |
+----+----+----+----+----+


-- Desired result:
+----+---------+
| ID | row_max |
+----+---------+
|  1 |       4 |
|  2 |      11 |
|  3 |       4 |
|  4 |       2 |
|  5 |       8 |
+----+---------+
```

With two or three columns, I'd just write it out in `iif` or a `CASE` statement.

```
select ID
  , iif(C1 > C2, C1, C2) row_max
from table
```

But with more columns this gets cumbersome fast. Is there a nice way to get this row-wise maximum? In R, this is called a "parallel maximum", so I'd love something like

```
select ID
  , pmax(C1, C2, C3, C4) row_max
from table
```

Comment: take a look at pivot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about unpivoting the data to get the result? You've said tsql but not what version of SQL Server. In SQL Server 2005+ you can use [`CROSS APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to convert the columns into rows, then get the max value for each row:

```
select id, row_max = max(val)
from yourtable
cross apply
(
  select c1 union all
  select c2 union all
  select c3 union all
  select c4
) c (val)
group by id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d60c/3). Note, this could be abbreviated by using a [table value constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx).

This could also be accomplished via the [UNPIVOT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) function in SQL Server:

```
select id, row_max = max(val)
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  val
  for col in (C1, C2, C3, C4)
) piv
group by id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d60c/4).  Both versions gives a result:

```
| id | row_max |
|----|---------|
|  1 |       4 |
|  2 |      11 |
|  3 |       4 |
|  4 |       2 |
|  5 |       8 |
```

Comment: is cross apply neater than pivot?

Comment: @FabianBigler Pivot converts rows of data into columns, this is the opposite. It's taking the multiple columns and turning it into rows to get the max value.

Comment: I thought you could use unpivot too instead of cross apply

Comment: @FabianBigler I just included an unpivot version in my answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But which one should I use?

Comment: @FabianBigler You can use either one.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT id, (SELECT MAX(c) 
            FROM (
                SELECT c = C1
                UNION ALL
                SELECT c = C2
                UNION ALL
                SELECT c = C3
                UNION ALL
                SELECT c = C4
            ) as x(c)) maxC
FROM mytable
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7ca50/1)

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `cross apply`:

```
select t.id, m.maxval
from table t cross apply
     (select max(val) as maxval
      from (values (c1), (c2), (c3), (c4)) v(val)
     ) m
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  This and Giorgos's answer are the best so far.

Comment: Not my vote, but why's that? Care to elaborate on why this and Giorgos's are the best so far?

Comment: @bluefeet . . . Your answer requires aggregating over the entire data set.  The correlated subquery and `cross apply` only require aggregating within a small amount of data.

Comment: @bluefeet's answer has two suggestions actually, the first of them being the same as yours, only using slightly different syntax. Anyway, why do you think aggregation over the entire set once is worse then aggregation over a small set many times?

Comment: @AndriyM . . . When I wrote the comment, bluefeet didn't have two answers.  The main point is that general-purpose aggregation algorithms do not scale O(n) in both memory and processing, so doubling the number of rows should take more than twice the effort.  Operating on a single row should have additional performance advantages because the data is localized when aggregated.  Because this type of query is a special case, it is possible that there is some sort of optimization specifically for this case that I'm not aware of.