# Combine results of SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have done some looking into a *seemingly* simple task but haven't been able to find a simple solution.  I wanted to ask this question in the most simplest terms so that others, and myself, may benefit from similar situations.  I came across a query that needed to be refactored a little that produced some strange results.

What would be the best way to turn these results:

```
ID    Customer    CustomerID (US)    CustomerID (CA)   CustomerID (EU)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1     XYZ         XYZ - US           NULL              NULL
2     XYZ         NULL               XYZ - CA          NULL
3     XYZ         NULL               NULL              XYZ - EU
```

Into this:

```
ID    Customer    CustomerID (US)    CustomerID (CA)   CustomerID (EU)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1     XYZ         XYZ - US           XYZ - CA          XYZ - EU
```

If there is more than one approach, what would be the best way following the most current best practices?

Here is some sample code that currently produces the first results:

```
    SELECT Header.ID,
        Header.Customer,
        CASE Detail.Location
            WHEN 'US' THEN Detail.CustomerID
            ELSE NULL
        END AS [CustomerID (US)],
        CASE Detail.Location
            WHEN 'CA' THEN Detail.CustomerID
            ELSE NULL
        END AS [CustomerID (CA)],
        CASE Detail.Location
            WHEN 'EU' THEN Detail.CustomerID
            ELSE NULL
        END AS [CustomerID (EU)]
    FROM dbo.Header AS Header 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Detail AS Detail
            ON Header.ID = Detail.HeaderID
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Cant you just group by Header.Customer then MAX() the other columns?

Comment: looks like a pivot question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want aggregation:

```
SELECT MIN(Header.ID) as ID, Header.Customer,
       MAX(CASE Detail.Location WHEN 'US' THEN Detail.CustomerID
           END) AS [CustomerID (US)],
       MAX(CASE Detail.Location WHEN 'CA' THEN Detail.CustomerID
           END) AS [CustomerID (CA)],
       MAX(CASE Detail.Location WHEN 'EU' THEN Detail.CustomerID
           END) AS [CustomerID (EU)]
FROM dbo.Header LEFT OUTER JOIN
     dbo.Detail Detail
     ON Header.ID = Detail.HeaderID
GROUP BYHeader.Customer
```

Comment: +1 for the example.  This solution works very well however, I haven't taken a look at the execution plans yet to see how much of a performance impact the aggregates caused.