# How to display the sql data horizontal using Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have attached the screenshot of the sql query and the results table, Here i would to view the table Horizontal.

like

|iFruit|iPlant|Pat on the back|The Incredebles|

|2     | 1    |    1           |   1          |

Please help me to write the pivot function to get the above format.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13377114/673707

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your query in following order.

```
select <column list> from (select query) as S
Pivot
(
  sum(col)
  for col in (column list)
)as pvt
```

Example:

```
Select iFruit, iPlant, [Pat on the Back], [The Incredibles] 
 from (select r.award_name as Awardname, 
   count(r.award_name) as Awardcount
   from associate_L_award p, asociate_information q, award_list r
   where p.Id = q.id
   and p.award_no = r.award_no
   and q.id='290007'
   group by r.award_name) as S
 Pivot
 (
   sum (AwardCount)
   for AwardName in (iFruit, iPlant, [Pat on the Back], [The Incredibles]) 
 ) as pvt
```

**Note**: If your base query is returning more **Award Names** then you have to manually add them in this query. Plus, if you have space in award name like "Pat on the back" then enclose that string in "[]".

**Edit:** After a lot of RnD, I got the solution. 
Scenario: Number of rows (which in turns become columns in pivot) return by the main are not fixed, they are dynamic.
Solution:

1. Create a `temp table` to store the output of your main query. However
   this is not mandatory and you can use your main query where-ever
   required. But from performance and readability point, you may use
   temp table.

> ```
> SELECT * 
> INTO   #temp 
> FROM   (SELECT r.award_name        AS Awardname, 
>                Count(r.award_name) AS Awardcount 
>         FROM   associate_l_award p, 
>                asociate_information q, 
>                award_list r 
>         WHERE  p.id = q.id 
>                AND p.award_no = r.award_no 
>                AND q.id = '290007' 
>         GROUP  BY r.award_name) AS S
> ```

2. Write following set of queries to build your pivot query.

> ```
> DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(1000) 
> DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)      
> SELECT @str = COALESCE(@str+',', '') + awardname 
> FROM   #temp 
>
> SET @sql = N'select ' + @str + ' from (SELECT Awardname, Awardcount FROM #temp) as S 
> Pivot 
> (   
>   sum(Awardcount)   
>   for Awardname in (' + @str + ')  
> )as pvt;'
> ```

3. Now you only need to execute following command to get desired result.

> `EXECUTE Sp_executesql @sql`

Comment: hi Amnesh, Thanks for your reply.  Awardname and Awardcount are dynamic columns. Can you help me how to handle this?

Comment: @DelwinSamuel means? You are getting values for these columns, right?

Comment: Ya getting the values correctly, But i have around 16 awards in my database, based on q.id value the awards list will vary.. here q.id is '290007' for example another associate '22222' the awards list will vary.. can you help me on that?

Comment: But in order to display in that manner, you have to mention the column names... How many such ID's do you have?

Comment: Can you help me on this?

Comment: @DelwinSamuel I have updated my answer, please check. This will fix your problem.