# How can I append a column in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, append, multiple-columns

I've tried different things in SQL Server 2012 to append the columns. CONCAT merges the columns look like this: catdogparrot whereas I want it be in a list like:

```
 cat
 dog
 parrot
```

I've also tried the + in SQL, giving me the same result. I saw '||' as well, but for some reason it says wrong syntax at the second pipe. Is there a way to append a column to a new one? Or would I have to create a new column from the multiple columns? These columns are in the same table. Any suggestions are advice are greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Don't do this to yourself. What you are trying to do is shove a bunch of values into a single column. This violates 1NF and is a serious pain to work with. If you do this, you will have to parse this column every time you need to query it. Instead you should normalize your data.

Comment: `concat(Field1, ' - ', field2, ' - ', field3)`  but why this seems like it could cause trouble downstream

Comment: I couldn't understand this, so you want to transpose column values to rows, or what?

Comment: Can you check this if it's beneficial: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13377114/673707

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but you could try to use

```
CONCAT(' - ', `column1`, ' - ', `column2`, ' - ', ... `column999`)
```

Comment: Perfect, this allowed me to split it at those instances, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually this could help you: You can set the separator to any sequence, even to `CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)`, which is a windows line break.

```
DECLARE @dummyTbl TABLE(animal VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl
VALUES('cat'),('dog'),('parrots');

DECLARE @separator VARCHAR(5)= ' / ';

SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT @separator + animal 
    FROM @dummyTbl AS dt
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,LEN(@separator),'');
```