# Convert table column and table row in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table like that:

```
Day   Item   Value
1      2      5
1      1      4
2      3      7
3      1      6
```

Now, i want to select like below:

```
Item  Day1   Day2   Day3
1     4      blank  6
2     5      blank  blank
3     balnk  7      blank
```

with Day1, Day2, Day3 are value of column 'Day' in first table.

Everyone help me. 
Sorry about my poor!

Comment: Where is your code! What have you tried so far?

Comment: sorry, i have no idea for this problem

Comment: I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free coding service

Comment: Can please give some more details?

Comment: i need idea, don't code

Comment: What is Day1, Day2,...? Where does it come from? Please give more details about what you want to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple way to transpose columns and rows in Sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql)

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: **`Hint :`** You have to use dynamic sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, I can provide you this code. I'm not sure, if this is what you want to do / expect. This example works in SQL Server.

```
SELECT 
    Item,
    case when [DAY] = 1 then value else '' end as Day1,
    case when [DAY] = 2 then value else '' end as Day2,
    case when [DAY] = 3 then value else '' end as Day3
FROM
    [yourtablename]
```

Now you added `orcale` as tag. I don't know oracle, but maybe my example provides you a way.

Comment: thank for help, i'll try