# display data horizontally

Tags: sql, pivot

I have written a code like this

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable
```

This gets the output in a vertical view.

```
ID | Name
1  | John
2  | Mckensy
3  | Valneech
4  | Zeebra
```

However, I need to display it horizontally.

```
1    | 2       | 3        | 4
John | Mckensy | Valneech | Zeebra
```

How can one do this?

Comment: could you provide table structure?

Comment: That is called `pivoting`. In which engine are you trying to accomplish? (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle...)

Comment: Create table testable( id into, name char(20))

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot for achieving the requirement. Since you have not posted any data model, I have drafted a rough logic. Please check it if works

Static

```
select * from your table
pivot (name for id in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) as anyrandomname
```

For your reference you can refer to this link.

```
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample/
```

Comment: Here you have input id 1 2 3 4 static. But I have lot of data. I don't want to put static data.  What should do it?

Comment: which database are you using @Md.AbdulMasudRana

Comment: try this link @Md.AbdulMasudRana http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

```
select (select Name from test where ID=1) as 1,
       (select Name from test where ID=2) as 2,
       (select Name from test where ID=3) as 3,
       (select Name from test where ID=4) as 4
from test
group by 1,2,3,4
```