# How to display data horizontally in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

How do I display my table data horizontally?

This is my table definition

```
create table [User]
(
    Id int primary key identity(1,1),
    Name varchar(50),
    Gender varchar(10)
)
```

This is the data I have in my SQL Server table

```
+====+=======+========+
| Id | Name  | Gender |
+====+=======+========+
| 1  | Fahad | Male   |
+----+-------+--------+
| 2  | Saad  | Male   |
+----+-------+--------+
| 3  | Asif  | Male   |
+====+=======+========+
```

and I want to show it horizontally like this

```
+========+=======+======+======+
| Id     | 1     | 2    | 3    |
+========+=======+======+======+
| Name   | Fahad | Saad | Asif |
+--------+-------+------+------+
| Gender | Male  | Male | Male |
+========+=======+======+======+
```

Comment: Use PIVOT https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: You will end up with a lot of columns. You know that right?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a combination of `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT`?

(Although your columns need to be of the same type for this to work, which I've changed in your table, or you can just `CAST` in a `SELECT`/`CTE` etc)

```
CREATE table [User](
Id int primary key identity(1,1),
Name varchar(50),
Gender varchar(50)
)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [User] ON

INSERT INTO [User](Id,Name,Gender) VALUES 
(1, 'Fahad','Male'),
(2,'Saad','Male'),
(3,'Asif','Male')

SELECT * FROM [User]
UNPIVOT ([Value] FOR Cols IN ([Name],[Gender])) Unp
PIVOT   (MAX([Value]) FOR Id IN ([1],[2],[3])) Piv


Cols    1      2      3
------  ------ ------ -------
Gender  Male   Male   Male
Name    Fahad  Saad   Asif

(2 row(s) affected)
```

`CASE` can also be used to achieve the same - there are tons of examples on SO.

Edit: Excellent example [Simple way to transpose columns and rows in Sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql) 
(and this is probably a dup of that question)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems we might need to do combination of `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT`.

Try below, It may provide you the exact result as what you expect. Please change your design first

```
Gender varchar(10) to Gender varchar(50)
```

Try below,

```
;WITH cte AS(
                SELECT *
                FROM   [User]
                       UNPIVOT([Value] FOR Cols IN ([Name], [Gender])) Unp
                       PIVOT(MAX([Value]) FOR Id IN ([1], [2], [3])) Piv
            )
SELECT Cols  AS Id,
       [1],
       [2],
       [3]
FROM   cte
ORDER BY
       Id       DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a stored procedure that works on any given table. It presumes that the table key is in the first column.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[Invert]','P') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE [Invert]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[Invert] @tbl sysname, @top int=1000 AS
DECLARE @key sysname SELECT @key=COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME=@tbl AND ORDINAL_POSITION=1
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @ids varchar(max)
SET @sql='SELECT TOP '+CAST(@top as varchar(9))+' @out=COALESCE(@out+'','','''')+QUOTENAME('
    +QUOTENAME(@key)+') FROM '+QUOTENAME(@tbl)+' ORDER BY '+QUOTENAME(@key)
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@out varchar(max) OUTPUT', @out=@ids OUTPUT
SET @sql=NULL
SELECT @sql=COALESCE(@sql+' UNION ALL ','')+'SELECT '''+COLUMN_NAME+''' AS '+QUOTENAME(@key)
    + ',* FROM (SELECT TOP '+CAST(@top as varchar(9))+' '+QUOTENAME(@key)+' k,CAST('
    + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)+'as varchar(8000)) m FROM '+QUOTENAME(@tbl)
    +' ORDER BY '+QUOTENAME(@key)+') t PIVOT (MAX(m) FOR k IN ('+@ids+')) x'+CHAR(13)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c WHERE TABLE_NAME=@tbl AND c.ORDINAL_POSITION>1
    ORDER BY c.ORDINAL_POSITION
EXECUTE(@sql)
GO
```

The stored procedure uses PIVOT to pivot each column. UNPIVOT is nice, but can only be used if all the columns have the same type (including length). The procedure generates a dynamic SELECT that uses UNION ALL operator to combine  PIVOTs for each column (except the key). The list of key values (@ids) is also dynamically generated because the PIVOT command expects an explicit column list.

Then you can call it like this:

```
EXEC Invert [User]
```

The second optional parameter is the top clause (the default is 1000). Below is an example that returns a maximum of 5 rows:

```
EXEC Invert [User], 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table [User]
(
    Id int primary key identity(1,1),
    Name varchar(50),
    Gender varchar(50),sal varchar(50)
)SET IDENTITY_INSERT [User] ON
```

--give same data type and size to all of field

```
    INSERT INTO [User](Id,Name,Gender,sal) VALUES 
    (1, 'Fahad','Male',10000),
    (2,'Saad','Male',20000),
    (3,'Asif','Male',30000)

SELECT * FROM [User]
UNPIVOT ([Val] FOR Cols IN (name,gender,sal)) Unp
PIVOT   (MAX([Val]) FOR Id IN ([1],[2],[3])) Piv


Cols    1      2      3
------  ------ ------ -------
Gender  Male   Male   Male
Name    Fahad  Saad   Asif
sal     10000  20000  30000
```