# How to Switch rows into columns and columns into rows in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rows

Hi I have a table like below,.

```
Stat                        Points  TeamA TeamB     Date
Highest Total               248     5       387     2016-05-14
Lowest Total                153     2       5       2016-05-11
Highest Successful Chase    195     5       386     2016-05-07
Lowest Score Defended       211     5       4       2016-05-18
```

I want the result like,

```
        Highest Total   Lowest Total    Highest Chase   Low Defended
  A     248             153             195             211     
  B     5               2               5               5   
  C     384             5               386             4   
  D     2016-05-14      2016-05-11      2016-05-07      2016-05-18
```

Help me to get the result, I'm newer one for the sql server.

Comment: The first table version is horrible, the second slightly better... Can't really understand any of them...

Comment: The first line of the First table is column name of it's.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple way to transpose columns and rows in Sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql)

Comment: Can you not perform this rotation in a presentation layer, e.g. an application or report builder? You desired result has columns containing data of different types - which in practice means it's either not going to happen in SQL or you've got to destroy your type information and make everything strings.

Comment: There is a variant data type. Never used it but it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot and unpivot, whatever this 'A', 'B', .. really mean.
It also shows casting different types to common `varchar(20)`. You may need different cast according to your requierments.

```
select rowType,
  max(case ut.stat when 'Highest Total' then value end) as [Highest Total],
  max(case ut.stat when 'Lowest Total' then value end) as [Lowest Total],
  max(case ut.stat when 'Highest Chase' then value end) as [Highest Chase],
  max(case ut.stat when 'Lowest Score Defended' then value end) as [Lowest Defended]
from t
cross apply (
    select * 
    from (
        values 
        ('A', cast(points as varchar(20)), stat),
        ('B', cast(TeamA as varchar(20)), stat),        
        ('C', cast(TeamB as varchar(20)), stat),
        ('D', cast(Date as varchar(20)), stat)
     ) ut(rowType, value, stat) )ut
group by rowType
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Serg. But it have some problem about the datatype variants int and date. But it helps me a lot.

Comment: It works Fine, but the order is Changed. How can I get it with the same order I want.

Comment: Add `ORDER BY rowType` after GROUP BY