# Convert Column to row (pivot)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

i need to make the data in the column to be column head

this is the current result from my query .. :

select employee_id,reimbursement_type,SUM(amount) as [total amount],reimbursement_status from md_reimbursement
group by employee_id,reimbursement_type,reimbursement_status

[image]

and i want it to be like this :

[image]

*just ignore the Status field

so the data reimbursement_type to become a column head and it SUM each amount.

i already tried using pivot but didnt get what i expected.

thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql/13377114#13377114

Answer (score 2):

Prepared a sample according to your requirement. As you have mentioned to ignore Status, I am not considering it into the query.

```
select * from 
(
select employee_id,reimbursement_type,amount from md_reimbursement
)src
pivot
(
sum(amount) for reimbursement_type in ([Biaya Dinas],[Other],[Transport],[Uang Makan])
)pvt
```

Comment: thx maulik, it works.