# SQL group rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table

```
ID | Customer | Type    | Value |
---+----------+---------+-------+
 1 | John     | Income  |   50  |
 2 | John     | Income  |   20  |
 3 | Mike     | Outcome |  150  |
 4 | Robert   | Income  |  100  |
 5 | John     | Outcome |  300  |
```

Want a table like that;

```
        | John | Mike | Robert | 
--------+------+------+--------+
 Income |  70  |   0  |   100  |
 Outcome| 300  | 150  |     0  |
```

What should be the SQL Query? Thanks

The problem is Customers and Type are not static they are dynamic.
What I tried:

```
  SELECT 'TotalIncome' AS TotalSalaryByDept, 
    [John], [Mike]
    FROM
    (SELECT Customer, Income
     FROM table001) AS a
    PIVOT
    (
     SUM(Income)
     FOR ID IN ([John], [Mike])
    ) AS b;
```

Comment: Have a look at [PIVOT()](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/pivot.php)

Comment: show us your pivot query and we'll point out how to get it to work. You really need to be showing this stuff in your questions, from a quick skim of your previous questions there is minimal effort going in on your part. We're not a free coding service, show us your attempts and we'll help.

Comment: Show what have you tried.

Comment: The problem is Customers are not static they are dynamic.

Comment: Then you need a dynamic pivot query.  Have you Googled for that?

Comment: The question looks very similar to this question, which has a very detailled answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql

Comment: @RichBenner  sorry for wrong question. I edited my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quick dynamic pivot.  We use a CROSS APPLY to unpivot the desired measures.

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) 
Select  @SQL = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(Customer) From YourTable Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
 Select [Type],' + @SQL + '
  From (
        Select Item=A.Customer,B.* 
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply (
                       Select Type=''Income'' ,Value=A.Income Union All
                       Select Type=''Outcome'',Value=A.Outcome
                     ) B
       ) A
 Pivot (sum(value) For Item in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

[image]

> **EDIT - For the Revised Question**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(Customer) From YourTable Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
 Select [Type],' + @SQL + '
  From  (Select Customer,Type,Value from YourTable ) A
 Pivot (Sum(Value) For [Customer] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: @Guest I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Guest See Edit/Revised section

Comment: thank you million times.

Comment: @Guest Happy to help

Answer (score -1):

The Table as you have it is how it should be in your SQL database.  Columns are reserved for classifying your data, and rows are where you add new instances.

What you need to do is set up your ASP, Excel Pivot Table, or whatever you are using to **display** the data to format it into a horizontal table.  I would need to know what you are using to interface with your database to give you an example.

Comment: edited my question

Comment: This answer makes no sense at all.  There is nothing about this question that relates to "display"