# Convert name-value-pair table into a single-row table having the names as columns, without hard-coding the column names

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Perhaps the xml functions would help with this?

I couldn't find any example that wasn't hard coding the column names.
I got this far:

```sql
CREATE PROC dbo.OneRowProc
(
    @Id DECIMAL(15,0)
)
AS BEGIN

    SELECT * 
    into #NameValuePair
    from NameValueTableFunction(@Id)

    DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT '
    UPDATE  #NameValuePair
    SET     @Sql = @Sql + '''' + Value + ''' AS [' + Name + '],'

    SET     @Sql = SUBSTRING(@Sql, 1, LEN(@Sql) - 1)
    EXEC    (@Sql)

END
GO
```

But, unfortunately, the results of a proc, you can't get it into a temp table b/c you can't `select * into #temptable from myproc`

**DATA**

`#NameValuePair` would look like:

```
Name        Value
----        -----
Color       Red
Age         43
Mood        Happy
```

Results would look like:

```
Color Age Mood
----- --- -----
Red   43  Happy
```

**UPDATE**

I'm able now to get it into a temp table, but I still can't get it into a table valued function:

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PolicyInformation') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #PolicyInformation
SELECT
  * INTO #PolicyInformation
FROM PolicyInformation(932774264229946)/*60272329046394*/
DECLARE @ColumnDefs AS varchar(max)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT
  @ColumnDefs = ISNULL(@ColumnDefs + ' VARCHAR(MAX),', '')
  + QUOTENAME(Name)
FROM (SELECT
  *
FROM #PolicyInformation) T
SET @ColumnDefs = @ColumnDefs + ' VARCHAR(MAX)'
PRINT @ColumnDefs
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PolicyInformationTable') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #PolicyInformationTable
CREATE TABLE #PolicyInformationTable (
  Dummy int
)
DECLARE @Columns varchar(max),
        @AlterTable varchar(max)
SET @AlterTable = 'ALTER TABLE #PolicyInformationTable ADD ' + @ColumnDefs
EXEC (@AlterTable)
ALTER TABLE #PolicyInformationTable DROP COLUMN Dummy
SELECT
  *
FROM #PolicyInformationTable
SELECT
  @Columns = ISNULL(@Columns + ',', '')
  + '''' + Value + ''' as ' + QUOTENAME(Name)
FROM #PolicyInformation
PRINT @Columns
EXEC ('INSERT #PolicyInformationTable SELECT ' + @Columns)
SELECT
  *
FROM #PolicyInformationTable
```

Comment: uhm....what?...

Comment: can you post NameValueTableFunction and some expected output? And you certainly can store the results in a temp table via an insert statement.

Comment: @scsimon ok look now

Comment: Ah, you are wanting a pivot my friend. Specifically a dynamic pivot. There are many examples. I just did another one a few days ago.( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42009800/sql-transpose-a-column-to-row/42010144#42010144). Also here is a great reference( http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/)

Comment: @scsimon, I love dynamic stuff. That's what I live for (｡◕‿◕｡)

Comment: I hear ya @toddmo

Comment: lol downvote...

Comment: Wasn't me on the DV for what it's worth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the reference provided, here's how you could accomplisht hat

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tempValuePair') is not null drop table #tempValuePair
select
'Color' as Name,
'Red' as Value
into #tempValuePair
union all
select
'Age','43'
union all
select
'Mood','Happy'



DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(Name)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM #tempValuePair) AS Courses

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #tempValuePair
    PIVOT(MAX(Value) 
          FOR Name IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Comment: That's very neat. You wouldn't happen to know the way to get the end result of that back into a temp table would you? That was the limitation with my attempt.

Comment: Since you don't know how many columns there will be before execution, you'll have to use OPENROWSET @toddmo