# Split row results to column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, row

I am trying to create a query that pulls all customer info from our database, but because there are often multiple contact persons behind 1 company, I get the same company listed in multiple rows. I would like to have each company only show up in 1 row and place additional contact persons in new columns instead,

Current results:

```
Company    |   Contact person
-------------------------------
Company 1  |   Alex
Company 1  |   Tom
Company 2  |   James
Company 2  |   Andy
```

Desired results:

```
Company    |   Contact person 1  |  Contact person 2
----------------------------------------------
Company 1  |   Alex              |  Tom
Company 2  |   James             |  Andy
```

Here is approx. what my query looks like:

```
SELECT Customer.Company, CustomerAdditionalInfo.ContactPerson
FROM Customer LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomerAdditionalInfo
```

Thank you for your time,

Comment: You are wanting a PIVOT, specifically DYNAMIC PIVOT if there could be more than 2 contacts. [Here's one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42076379/6167855) that I answered already but there are tons on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: thank you scsimon I will give those a try

Comment: No worries at all @Senko

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 SELECT Customer.Company,GROUP_CONCAT(Customer.ContactPerson) AS 'AllContactPerson'
FROM Customer GROUP BY Customer.Company
```

this will give you as under result (if ContactPerson details comes from `Customer` table. )

```
Company    |   AllContactPerson 
--------------------------------
Company 1  |   Alex,Tom
```

Comment: I am getting 'GROUP_CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: that's because it's MySQL syntax not SQL Server. Keval was trying to do something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)