# SQL::Match duplicate values and concatenate the results in a comma separated string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The task I am trying to achieve is the following: 
I have a table with two columns : - u0 and u1. The values in the two columns sometimes are repeated, meaning that one value would appear in both u0 and u1 .

```
          u0                       u1    
1         A                         B 
2         B                         C
3         D                         B
4         B                         D
5         F                         E
```

If the table has one row: u0=A, u1=B and another row u0=B, u1=C then we can conclude that A,B and C all belong to the same user. The idea is to build a table with a column where every row contains a list of U entries that belong to one user in a comma separated string.

Desiered output:

```
       IDs
u0    A,B,C,D
u1    E,F,G
```

The way I have approached the task is with the following :

```
select 
  distinct 
    stuff((  
        select ',' + u0
        from [db1]
        where u0 like u1 
        for xml path('')
 ),1,1,'')as uids 
from [db1]
```

But with this query in BigQuery I get the error :

> Error: Encountered " "FOR" "for "" at line 7, column 9. Was expecting:
>   ")" ...

I have tried with COALESCE as well , but with no success

```
SELECT uids = COALESCE(u1 + ',','') + u0
FROM [db1]
WHERE u0 in u1
```

and got this error message back :

> Error: Encountered " "IN" "in "" at line 3, column 12. Was expecting:

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your table reference is clearly legacy BigQuery, so I removed the inappropriate databases.

Comment: Current syntax: [String_agg](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#string_agg)... Old syntax: [Group_concat](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#group_concat)

Comment: you should use GROUP_CONCAT sql function check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42418641/split-row-results-to-column/42419232#42419232

Comment: Thank you all for the swift replies. I have one question : Is there some similar function to group_concat and string_agg  for the cases where the data is not VARCHAR but integer ? 

Thank you

Comment: You can use `ARRAY_AGG`, or you can use `STRING_AGG(CAST(x AS STRING))`. In your sample output above, how would you end up with `G` in the `u1` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that I entirely understand the question, but if you just want to get the string concatenation of distinct `u0` values that are in `u1`, you can do something like this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  STRING_AGG(DISTINCT u0)
FROM T
WHERE u0 IN (SELECT u1 FROM T);
```

As a self-contained example:

```
#standardSQL
WITH T AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM UNNEST(ARRAY<STRUCT<u0 STRING, u1 STRING>>[
    ('A', 'B'),
    ('B', 'C'),
    ('D', 'B'),
    ('B', 'D'),
    ('F', 'E')
  ])
)
SELECT 
  STRING_AGG(DISTINCT u0)
FROM T
WHERE u0 IN (SELECT u1 FROM T);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Elliott. When i tried the first proposed solution I just got back a one column table containing the values of both u0 and u1 but not in a comma separated string , but each observation in a separate field. 
The second example is not scalable given that  I have 3 million observations.