# How to have Dynamic Queryable Entities in OData v4 API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

In the task of building a web api using OData v4, entity and C#, I got stuck in the following problem. I have a view in my DB (SQL Server) that has some yearly info as rows, such as...

```
    |Year |Value |
     1985  8.7
     1986  8.8
```

But I need to serve them as columns:

```
    |1985 |1986 |
     8.7    8.8
```

The years are dynamic, I couldn't find a way to create a model class that is dynamic. Because of that, I couldn't find a way to serve the data in the controller. I was able to pivot the information using C# code, but OData doesn't serve it, because there was no corresponding model.

I tried to use a library called [MedallionOdata](http://www.codeducky.org/creating-dynamic-odata-grid-medallionodata-jquery-datatables/), it has a ODataEntity that was supposed to be dynamic and Queryable, but I couldn't make it work.

What is the best way to serve dynamic entities keeping the queryable aspects of OData?

Comment: I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql/13377114#13377114) has the answer you're looking for.

Comment: I used that post before to pivot the data on the DB, but that is not what I'm looking for, the problem is in the models... I was able to do it with "open types" in OData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OData has a concept of "open types" that I think will help you to achieve what you are looking for. They essentially let you add any properties onto an object.

If you are using the `ODataConventionModelBuilder`, it is as simple as adding a property of type `IDictionary<string, object>` to your model class like this:

```
public IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }
```

You can find more details here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/use-open-types-in-odata-v4

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much. Now the API is able to serve the open type, and some of the filters are working. I'm still figuring out a way to $select on the open types, such as, if I wanted the API to return only the values of the year 1985...

Comment: That's great, can you accept the answer if it has solved the issue :)

You should be able to do `$select` and `$filter` on the dynamic properties as though they were normal properties

Comment: I'm able to select on the properties that are not dynamic, when I try to `$select` on the year, I get the following error: `{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. An identifier was expected at position 0.",
        "innererror": {
            "message": "An identifier was expected at position 0.",
            "type": "Microsoft.OData.ODataException",
            "stacktrace": "  ...`

Comment: Could you create a new question for this as it is a different problem to this question and that means that there will be a lot more space to see the issue. Make sure that you post the URL that you used in the questions

Comment: Yes!!! I will do it right now. =]... Am I supposed to close this question? How do I do it?

Comment: Don't forget to make this question as answered so that other people know that it is answered :)

Comment: Ok!! =] The other question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46976034/how-to-select-on-odata-open-data-type-query-not-valid-error