# How to do rows to column in SQL Server with count

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

How do I simply switch Rows with Column in SQL with count? Is there any way to do?
Actually i want against each unique mobile no with count and product name side by side means if two mobile no in table then count = 2 and side of that two product1,product2 shows in output.

ie turn this result:

```
Srno    Name| Mobile| Count  |  ProductName
1       xyz   1234       1       LNM
2       PQR   5678       1       VCD
3       xyz   1234       1       KLM
4       PQR   5678       1       NMG
```

into this:

```
Srno    Name| Mobile| Count  |  ProductName1  | ProductName2 
1       xyz   1234       2       LNM              KLM
2       PQR   5678       2       VCD              NMG
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple way to transpose columns and rows in Sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a limited `product`s then you use `row_number()` & do *conditional* aggregation :

```
select min(srno) as srno, name, Mobile, count(*) as cnt,
       max(case when seq = 1 then ProductName end) as ProductName1,
       max(case when seq = 2 then ProductName end) as ProductName2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name, Mobile order by srno) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
group by name, Mobile;
```

Comment: output gives duplicate rows comes in result. i want distinct mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT 
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS Srno,
    T1.name,
    T1.Mobile,
    SUM(T1.xCount + T2.xCount) as cnt,
    max(T1.ProductName) as Product1,
    max(T2.ProductName) as Product2
FROM Table1 as T1
LEFT JOIN Table1 AS T2 ON T1.name = T2.name
                      AND T2.srno > T1.srno
GROUP BY T1.name, T1.Mobile
ORDER BY Srno
```