# Transpose columns to rows with ANSI sql

Tags: sql, transpose

```
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 4  |
| 5  |
+----+
```

Output as row

```
1 2 4 5
```

**Without** use of Pivot method ,**no** hardcoding like checking with case with when 1 = 1.**No** dynamic Sql .with out any inbuilt function.

I have searched questions but could not find anything in pure sql
Is there a way?

Comment: I don't think there is such a construct with ANSI sql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple way to transpose columns and rows in Sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know you have four values, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then id end) as id_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then id end) as id_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then id end) as id_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then id end) as id_4       
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

I'm not sure if this fits your requirements.  If you are looking for something with a variable number of columns, then you need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: If i dont know the exact num of row for that col then dynamic sql is the option..?

Comment: @DotNetDev19 . . . If you want the values in separate columns.

Answer (score 1):

Most SQL databases support some sort of group concatenation ability.  For example, in MySQL we could use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id SEPARATOR ' ') AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

The ANSI standard may not define anything, but SQL Server, Oracle, and Postgres, to name a few, can do something similar to the above.

Answer (score 1):

I would use *correlated* subquery & do *conditional* aggergation since some `DBMS` doesn't have a `row_number()` :

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Seq = 1 THEN Id END) AS ID1,
       . . . 
       MAX(CASE WHEN Seq = 4 THEN Id END) AS ID4
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table t1 WHERE t1.id <= t.id) AS Seq
      FROM table t
     ) t;
```

However, this method might fail if the `ID` is not in Sequential manner if so, then you would need to use `PK` (`IDENTITY` Column) that specify column ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your database supports the **LISTAGG** function of [ANSI SQL:2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2016):
It is a function to transform values from a group of rows into a delimited string.

See syntax as well as database support and alternatives [here](https://modern-sql.com/feature/listagg):

> **Listagg** is an *ordered set function*, which require the `within group` clause to specify an order. The minimal syntax is:
>   `LISTAGG(<expression>, <separator>) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY …)`