# SQL Server query for this scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with data like this in SQL Server:

```
date        batch name              id              locatio
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Jul-2010    BPRGNMCTHKDKS621010070  Kodak 42        GREATER NOIDA
Nov-2010    BPRHYMCTHHPPS607210600  HYD_HP_KV-124   HYDERABAD
Dec-2010    BPRDLMCTHHPPS613110839  Alpha 112       DELHI
Dec-2010    BPRHYMCTHHPPS607210652  HYD_HP_6J-97    HYDERABAD
Feb-2011    BPRHYMCTHHPPS607211671  HYD-HP-KV-128   HYDERABAD
Jan-2011    BTPHYMCTHHPPS607211712  HYD-HP-HPT-246  HYDERABAD
```

I need output like

```
date , batch name , id , location 1 , loct 2 , loc 3 , loc4 and so on ..
```

I need the counts on the base of batch name or id.

Example output:

```
date batch name id    delhi hyd bang etc etc
---------------------------------------------
1    gh          xyz   34   45  6
```

Comment: This example output is not helpful. Where do the column names "delhi","hyd","bang" come from? What about etc? What are the row data?

Comment: Maybe this post could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql Regards

Comment: i think you are expecting pivot logic.. if 34,45 these values are  location values means you can go to pivot logic

Comment: column names "delhi","hyd","bang" come from? What about etc - from location column which is in main table .

Answer (score 0):

here is a link about a possible answer:

[Simple way to transpose columns and rows in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql)

Hope it helps