# Show multiple rows in already defined columns of gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have the following gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTimeline" ShowHeader="true"  runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
<Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="8" ItemStyle-Width="25%" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="2" ItemStyle-Width="25%" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="6" ItemStyle-Width="25%" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="4" ItemStyle-Width="25%" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And the following sql table:

```
Id   |  type  |  date

2    |    8   |  22/09/1997   
1    |    6   |  22/09/1998   
3    |    4   |  22/09/1999
```

What I want is to run the sql rows and go filling each column with the date corresponding to the type (only 1 row). Each datafield is a type. What is the best way to do this, later getting access to each id normally?

I expected this:

```
8                 2                 6              4
22/09/1997      null          22/09/1998       22/09/1999
```

Comment: It appears you’re trying to derive a new table from the *values* of an existing table, and bind to _that_ tables columns, right?

Comment: Yeah, more or less. I want only row.

Comment: You should look into PIVOT or conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're limiting to just those values, then creating a simple view and binding to *it* might be the simplest way to go.  For example:

```
CREATE VIEW view_for_gridview_binding AS
  SELECT DISTINCT
    eight.[date] as '8'
    , two.[date] as '2'
    , six.[date] as '6'
    , four.[date] as '4'
  FROM table_for_gridview_question 
  LEFT JOIN table_for_gridview_question AS eight ON (eight.[type] = 8)
  LEFT JOIN table_for_gridview_question AS two ON (two.[type] = 2)
  LEFT JOIN table_for_gridview_question AS six ON (six.[type] = 6)
  LEFT JOIN table_for_gridview_question AS four ON (four.[type] = 4)
GO
```

Here's test:

```
CREATE TABLE table_for_gridview_question (
    Id int NOT NULL,
    [type] int NOT NULL,
    [date] date NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO table_for_gridview_question
SELECT 2, 8, '1997-09-22'
UNION
SELECT 1, 6, '1998-09-22'
UNION
SELECT 3, 4, '1999-09-22'
GO

CREATE VIEW view_for_gridview_binding AS
    SELECT DISTINCT
        eight.[date] as '8'
        , two.[date] as '2'
        , six.[date] as '6'
        , four.[date] as '4'
    FROM table_for_gridview_question 
    LEFT JOIN table_for_gridview_question AS eight ON (eight.[type] = 8)
    LEFT JOIN table_for_gridview_question AS two ON (two.[type] = 2)
    LEFT JOIN table_for_gridview_question AS six ON (six.[type] = 6)
    LEFT JOIN table_for_gridview_question AS four ON (four.[type] = 4)
GO

SELECT * FROM view_for_gridview_binding

DROP VIEW view_for_gridview_binding
DROP TABLE table_for_gridview_question
```

Results of `SELECT`:

```
8          2          6          4
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1997-09-22 NULL       1998-09-22 1999-09-22
```

If, however, your `type`s can be anything, you may want to consider reading up on `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` like what's described in the *Dynamic Pivot Version* part of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql).