# Is it possible to retrieve the data from table in transpose format

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, pivot-table, unpivot

I have a table which has data in the below format.

```
id | col1 | col2 | col3
1  | d11  | d21  | d31
2  | d12  | d22  | d32
3  | d13  | d23  | d33
4  | d14  | d24  | d34
5  | d15  | d25  | d35
6  | d16  | d26  | d36
```

Is it possible to get the data in the below format.

```
id    |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6
col1  | d11 | d12 | d13 | d14 | d15 | d16
col2  | d21 | d22 | d23 | d24 | d25 | d26
col3  | d31 | d32 | d33 | d34 | d35 | d36
```

I don't even have a basic idea. Anything is welcome.

Comment: try `unpivot` then `pivot`.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: There is plenty of similar topics on SO .. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql>

Comment: @KubaDo : this link is for `sql server`, and here we have `mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this query for your output

```
with cte as (
select id, 'col1' as col , col1 as val from tab
union all
select id, 'col2' as col , col2 as val from tab
union all
select id, 'col3' as col , col3 as val from tab
)
select id, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6] from (
select id, col, val from cte
) as d
pivot (
max(val) for col in ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6] )
) as p
```

Please verify this and see if this works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpivot and re-pivot.  You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select col,
       sum(case when id = 1 then val end) as val_1,
       sum(case when id = 2 then val end) as val_2,
       sum(case when id = 3 then val end) as val_3,
       sum(case when id = 4 then val end) as val_4,
       sum(case when id = 5 then val end) as val_5,
       sum(case when id = 6 then val end) as val_6
from ((select id, 'col1' as col, col1 as val from t
      ) union all
      (select id, 'col2' as col, col2 as val from t
      ) union all
      (select id, 'col3' as col, col3 as val from t
      ) 
     ) t
group by col;
```

Comment: id from 1 to 6 are just examples, table may even have 10k records

Comment: @EeshwarAnkathi . . . (1) It is only possible to answer the question that you actually ask.  If you have a *different* question, then ask it as a *new* question.  (2) MySQL limits the number of columns in a table, so you cannot have thousands of columns.

Comment: id from 1 to 6 are not columns, those are entries(rows).