# How to correctly convert SQL rows to columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

Before someone mentions it, I have seen the exact same SQL question on Stack before and from my point of view, that's actually transposing columns to rows. What I'm trying to accomplish is as seen below in the photos, given the top one, I want to create a new table with the previous data that is flipped in this sense.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/13372276/6309111

Comment: If I was going there, I wouldn't start from here :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the conditional aggregation and `union all` as follows:

```
select name_new, 
       max(case when name = 'PersonA' then A end) as PersonA,
       max(case when name = 'PersonB' then A end) as PersonB,
       max(case when name = 'PersonC' then A end) as PersonC
from 
(select name, 'A1' name_new, A1 A from mytable union all
select name, 'A2' name_new, A2 A from mytable union all
select name, 'A3' name_new, A3 A from mytable union all
select name, 'A4' name_new, A4 A from mytable ) t
group by name_new
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/997790/6)

Comment: what does name_new represent?

Comment: see in the sub-query --> `(select name, 'A1' name_new,` -- I have just given alias to A1, A2 ... Also check updated answer, In final select I have given alias `name` to `name_new`

Comment: what have i not understood http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/997790/4

Comment: Ok, alias used in the GROUP BY was not correct. I have updated the answer with SQLFiddle'

Comment: one last thing if i was to create a new table with this new format, would I have to go about it manually or? I'm attempting to print all columns that are null for let's say Person A, which is why I was trying to manipulate the table and pass a where clause for null at column Person A

Comment: the current syntax prohibits me from adding a where clause to your statement, and if there was a way to embed yours into another one which had select all from (your select) where Person A is null

Comment: You can use `CREATE TABLE AS <SELECT QUERY FROM ANSWER HERE>` to create a new table using this.

Comment: To apply WHERE clause use `SELECT * FROM (<CURRENT_QUERY>) T WHERE ..`

Comment: its seems to be haulting at the group by name_...                                                     http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/997790/16

Comment: @ Popeye, thanks for all the help, but I am asking once more if your familiar with MySQL  executed in python, then you'll see I've a new unfortunate issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65507118/values-not-being-defined-when-outputted-in-python-mysql  if you knew anything in regards, would be much appreciated

Comment: Check the answer in you other question.