# Values not being defined when outputted in Python MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, pysqlite

Aided by a previously asked question see ([How to correctly convert SQL rows to columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65505115/how-to-correctly-convert-sql-rows-to-columns/65505294?noredirect=1#comment115812098_65505294)), I'm attempting to apply to a MySQL connector script written in python. As seen by @Popeye 's fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/997790/25, my attempt at returning all rows now with a null value for Person C but its output is seen below

```
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
     host="localhost",
     port="3307",
     user="root",
     passwd="#",
     database="#"
  )
mycursor = db.cursor()
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE trial157 (Name TEXT(13) NULL , A1 TEXT(13) NULL ,  A2 TEXT(13) NULL ,  A3 TEXT(13) NULL ,  A4 TEXT(13) NULL)")


sql = "INSERT INTO trial157(Name, A1, A2, A3, A4) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
val = [
  ('Person A', 'C', 'T', 'R', 'S'),
  ('Person B', 'M', 'V', 'R', 'S'),
  ('Person C', 'M', None , 'R', 'C')
]
mycursor.executemany(sql, val)
db.commit()


mycursor.execute("SELECT * From (select name_new, max(case when name = 'PersonA' then A end) as PersonA, max(case when name = 'PersonB' then A end) as PersonB, max(case when name = 'PersonC' then A end) as PersonC from (select name, 'A1' name_new, A1 A from trial157 union all select name, 'A2' name_new, A2 A from trial157 union all select name, 'A3' name_new, A3 A from trial157 union all select name, 'A4' name_new, A4 A from trial157 ) t group by name_new) t where PersonC is null")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for x in myresult:
  print(x)
```

```
 - OUTPUT
('A1', None, None, None)                                                                                     
('A2', None, None, None)
('A3', None, None, None)
('A4', None, None, None)
[Finished in 1.2s]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used wrong names.(in `case` expression names are used without `space`. You should use it exactly same as per `val`)

Replace

```
max(case when name = 'PersonA' then A end) as PersonA
```

With

```
max(case when name = 'Person A' then A end) as PersonA
```

See the `space` between `Person` and `A` in `name`. Do the same for `Person B` and `Person C`