# SQL Query Questions

Tags: sql

Hey I am not a SQl expert, but I am trying to query data and transpose it and am having trouble, here is what I am wanting:

make this

```
DateandTime             Val1    Val2
2020-01-01 00:00:00.000  10      20
```

look like this

```
DateandTime              Tag       Value
2020-01-01 00:00:00.000  Val1       10
2020-01-01 00:00:00.000  Val2       20
```

I am not sure what this kind of change this is called in SQL, but any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Also, this seems to be at least partly covered under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple way to transpose columns and rows in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most databases you can use a function called `unpivot`. Here is an example of it:

```sql
select
    *
from TAB_1
unpivot ( value  for tag in (val1, val2))
```

Results:

```
+-----------------------+----+-----+
|DATEANDTIME            |TAG |VALUE|
+-----------------------+----+-----+
|2020-01-01 00:00:00.000|VAL1|10   |
|2020-01-01 00:00:00.000|VAL2|20   |
+-----------------------+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

This is unpivoting.  A generic method is `union all`:

```
select dateandtime, 'Val1' as tag, val1 as value
from t
union all
select dateandtime, 'Val2', val2
from t;
```

Some databases have functionality -- specifically lateral joins -- to make this more efficient.

Comment: Tim's edit: removed alises from second half of the union query, as the database will just ignore them anyway +1.