# How to convert data in one row into one column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to transpose the data in my SQL Server table from table 1 into table 2.

Table 1:

| BatchNo | StartDate | StartTime | EndDate | EndTime | RecipeNo | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 210722-A0001 | 2021-07-22 | 08:00:00.000 | 2021-07-22 | 10:00:00.000 | 1 | Completed |
| 210722-A0002 | 2021-07-22 | 10:30:00.000 | 2021-07-22 | 11:45:00.000 | 2 | Completed |

Table 2 :

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 210722-A0001 | 210722-A0002 |
| 2021-07-22 | 2021-07-22 |
| 08:00:00.000 | 10:30:00.000 |
| 2021-07-22 | 2021-07-22 |
| 10:00:00.000 | 11:45:00.000 |
| 1 | 2 |
| Completed | Completed |

The number of columns in table 2 depends on the number of rows in table 1.

Comment: You should do more research. Normally you would use a function call pivot.

Comment: please refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql