# Produce weekly and quarterly stats from a monthly figure

Tags: sql, postgresql, alteryx

I have a sample of a table as below:

| Customer Ref | Bear Rate | Distance | Month | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABA-IFNL-001 | 1000 |  | 01/01/2022 | -135 |
| ABA-IFNL-001 | 1000 |  | 01/02/2022 | -135 |
| ABA-IFNL-001 | 1000 |  | 01/03/2022 | -135 |
| ABA-IFNL-001 | 1000 |  | 01/04/2022 | -135 |
| ABA-IFNL-001 | 1000 |  | 01/05/2022 | -135 |
| ABA-IFNL-001 | 1000 |  | 01/06/2022 | -135 |

I also have a sample of a calendar table as below:

| Date | Year | Week | Quarter | WeekDay | Qtr Start | Qtr End | Week Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04/11/2022 | 2022 | 45 | 4 | Fri | 30/09/2022 | 29/12/2022 | 1 |
| 05/11/2022 | 2022 | 45 | 4 | Sat | 30/09/2022 | 29/12/2022 | 2 |
| 06/11/2022 | 2022 | 45 | 4 | Sun | 30/09/2022 | 29/12/2022 | 3 |
| 07/11/2022 | 2022 | 45 | 4 | Mon | 30/09/2022 | 29/12/2022 | 4 |
| 08/11/2022 | 2022 | 45 | 4 | Tue | 30/09/2022 | 29/12/2022 | 5 |
| 09/11/2022 | 2022 | 45 | 4 | Wed | 30/09/2022 | 29/12/2022 | 6 |
| 10/11/2022 | 2022 | 45 | 4 | Thu | 30/09/2022 | 29/12/2022 | 7 |
| 11/11/2022 | 2022 | 46 | 4 | Fri | 30/09/2022 | 29/12/2022 | 1 |
| 12/11/2022 | 2022 | 46 | 4 | Sat | 30/09/2022 | 29/12/2022 | 2 |
| 13/11/2022 | 2022 | 46 | 4 | Sun | 30/09/2022 | 29/12/2022 | 3 |
| 14/11/2022 | 2022 | 46 | 4 | Mon | 30/09/2022 | 29/12/2022 | 4 |
| 15/11/2022 | 2022 | 46 | 4 | Tue | 30/09/2022 | 29/12/2022 | 5 |
| 16/11/2022 | 2022 | 46 | 4 | Wed | 30/09/2022 | 29/12/2022 | 6 |
| 17/11/2022 | 2022 | 46 | 4 | Thu | 30/09/2022 | 29/12/2022 | 7 |

How can I join/link the tables to report on revenue over weekly and quarterly periods using the calendar table? I can put into two tables if needed as an output eg:

| Quarter Starting | 31/12/2021 | 01/04/2022 | 01/07/2022 | 30/09/2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Quarter | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| Revenue | 500 | 400 | 540 | 540 |

| Week Date Start | 31/12/2021 | 07/01/2022 | 14/01/2022 | 21/01/2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Week | 41 | 42 | 43 | 44 |
| Revenue | 33.75 | 33.75 | 33.75 | 33.75 |

I am using alteryx for this but wouldnt mind explaination of possible logic in sql to apply it into the system
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I get into the answer, you're going to have an issue regarding data integrity. All the revenue data is aggregated at a monthly level, where your quarters start and end on someday within the month.

For example - Q4 starts September 30th (Friday) and ends Dec. 29th (Thursday).  You may have a day or two that bleeds from another month into the quarters which might throw off the data a bit (esp. if there's a large amount of revenue during the days that bleed into a quarter.

Additionally, your revenue is aggregated at a monthly level - unless you have more granular data (weekly, daily would be best), it doesn't make sense to do a weekly calculation since you'll probably just be dividing revenue by 4.

That being said - You'll want to use a `cross tab` feature in alteryx to get the data how you want it. But before you do that, we want to aggregate your data at a quarterly level first.

You can do this with an if statement or some other data cleansing tool (sorry, been a while since I used alteryx). Something like:

```
# Pseudo code - this won't actually work!

# For determining quarter
if (month) between (30/09/2022,29/12/2022) then 4
```

where you can derive the logic from your calendar table. Then once you have the quarter, you can join in the `Quarter Start date` based on your quarter calculation.

Now you have a nice clean table that might look something like this:

| Month | Revenue | Quarter | Quarter Start Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | -135 | 4 | 30/09/2022 |
| 01/01/2022 | -135 | 4 | 30/09/2022 |

Aggregate on your quarter to get a cleaner table

| Quarter Start Date | Quarter | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30/09/2022 | 4 | 300 |

Then use cross tab, where you pivot on the Quarter start date.

For SQL, you'd be [pivoting the data](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-pivot-table/). Essentially, taking the value from a row of data, and converting it into a column. It will look a bit janky because the data is so customized, but here's a good question that goes over pivioting - [Simple way to transpose columns and rows in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, I am now looking to bring back data on a daily level as you have described, think this will be the best way forward. Also new to alteryx and didnt know about the crosstab, so thanks for that suggestion too.