Join 3 Tables Horizontally
Why I'm trying to join 3 tables with some relationships between record ID's.  I'm pretty close, but I need to maybe pivot...?  Not sure if I need to pivot or group by or....? Maybe it's my joins? I've tried inner,outer, left, right... I just need it displayed horizontally in the query.
Tables/Fields
Table 1 = tcp_employeework.CostCode

Fields I need are RecordID, FullName, Status

Table 2 = tcp_company.CustomFieldValue

Fields needed are CustomFieldRecordID, Value

Table 3 = tcp_Company.CustomField

Fields needed are RecordID, Name

Table 3 is just field names for the custom field values in table 2.  Joined by Record ID's

Relationship should be tcp_company.customfieldvalue record ID to tcp_employeework.costcode recordid and tcp_company.customfieldvalue RecordID to tcp_company.customfield RecordID.

This query gets me close to what I need, but I need to pivot the data. There should only be a single row for each name in the FullName column and the values to be in separate columns with the data in the Name column being the headers.
SELECT 
nm.FullName,nm.Status,fs.Value,cf.Name from tcp_employeework.CostCode as nm 
right join tcp_company.CustomFieldValue as fs  on fs.CostCodeRecordId=nm.RecordId
inner join tcp_company.customfield as CF
on (fs.CustomFieldRecordId=cf.RecordId and nm.status=0)

Query Output
Desired Horizontal Output

If you're using MySQL how can you also be using SQL Server 2008. (Which has also been end of life for 5 years! Long past time to have upgraded.) SQL Server and MySQL are completely different products; please tag the one you are really using.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question. Post sample data and expected results as text.

Please provide table definitions, sample data for them and the result you want to achieve. Please format data as tables and code as code - so that they are all readable

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but you're doing a Right Join to tcp_company.CustomFieldValue, so you're going to get every record from that table, and the matching ones from tcp_employeework.CostCode. If the issue is that you are getting all the records for the "Values" field, then you'd either need to do a LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN. Left join will give you all records from tcp_employeework.CostCode and the ones matching from tcp_company.CustomFieldValue, and the INNER JOIN on tcp_company.customfield will give you only records from tcp_company.customfield that match with tcp_company.CustomFieldValue. I would write it like this
SELECT  nm.FullName
        ,nm.Status
        ,fs.Value
        ,cf.Name 
 
from tcp_employeework.CostCode as nm 
LEFT JOIN tcp_company.CustomFieldValue as fs on fs.CostCodeRecordId=nm.RecordId 
INNER tcp_company.customfield as CF on fs.CustomFieldRecordId=cf.RecordId 
WHERE nm.status=0'


well I want every record from value.  The problem is that for every record from value, the fullname gets duplicated by the join. I was hoping to get the data from value into separate columns instead of in the same column with duplicate full names.   I tried the suggested query and it gives the same result as the previous query. Edit: The data in cf.name should be the headers for value.

Ahh I see, so I did misunderstand! In that case, take a look at this. Seems to be what you are looking for.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13377114/21276561
